# Exporting lists to files

Tags: export, import

I am trying to write a program which will generate a list of objects and then exports it in a separate file and clears its memory. As an example I tried the following

```
Do[{Subscript[l, p] = Table[Subscript[l, p, i], {i, 10}];
  Export["\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\"l\", \"p\"]\).mnaz", 
   Compress[Subscript[l, p]], "String"]; Clear[Subscript[l, p]]}, {p, 
  1, 3}]
```

Of course, the above is just a sample (and my actual list(s) are more bulky (actually they are list of matrices)), but I hope it explains the spirit. I wanted to export each list separately so that I can get separate files like `l_1.mnaz`, `l_2.mnaz` etc., which I can import again by using the same type of code.

**Motivation**: I need to actually generate a huge list of data. However whatever I do, my system goes out of memory after 5000 loops, which itself takes a lot of time. One reason is that, I need to modify the list at each loop.  It seems 1000 loops takes a  reasonable time. Hence I am trying to break the loop into smaller chunks, export the data, and clear the memory for the next loop. `Clear[Subscript[l, p]]` is used for that purpose.

Comment: Subscripts don't work in any filename system I know of, so I think that will cause problems.

Comment: @Verbeia even if they did `"\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\"l\", \"p\"]\).mnaz"` would not work.  One could instead use: `ToString[Subscript[l, p], TeXForm] <> ".mnaz"` or if the file system supports it something besides `TeXForm`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

```
Do[
 l[p] = Table[Subscript[l, p, i], {i, 10}];
 Export["l_" <> ToString[p] <> ".mnaz", Compress@ l[p], "String"];
 l[p] =.
 , {p, 1, 3}
]
```

I replaced `Subscript[l, p]` with `l[p]`.  Frankly I don't see a reason to not simply use `temp = Table[ . . .` but I am trying to keep to the spirit of your example.

Comment: Beat me to it by seconds!

Comment: @Verbeia I'm trying to defend my rank against [the Hypno-Toad onslaught.](http://stackexchange.com/leagues/177/week/mathematica/2012-07-22/5#5) :o)

Comment: Hey! I need two votes for keeping Mr awake all night

Comment: @belisarius What's this? Are you colluding with the green one? ;-p

Comment: @Mr.Wizard that is just the [spirit](http://boingboing.net/2012/07/19/mr-wizard-dickery.html) ;-)

Comment: @YvesKlett LOL man that brings back memories!  I guess I now have license to be *more* grouchy: I'm just acting the part. >:D

Comment: @Mr.Wizard So now you can officially claim the [meme of the week](http://www.grantland.com/blog/hollywood-prospectus/post/_/id/53436/rembert-explains-the-80s-mr-wizards-a-dick) badge for awful didactics!

Comment: What is in a name?