# What is the difference between Set and SetDelayed?

Tags: syntax, assignment

I have a problem with defining a function and most of time I get confused by `Set` or `=` and `SetDelayed` or `:=`. 
I read the help section but I didn't find out what the difference is between defining a function as `y[x_] := ...` and `y[x_] = ...`

Comment: The documentation contains a [tutorial](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/ImmediateAndDelayedDefinitions.html) dedicated to explaining the difference.

Comment: I discuss that in great detail [here](http://www.verbeia.com/mathematica/tips/HTMLLinks/Tricks_P-Z_19.html).

Answer (score 62, accepted):

## References and intro

First, let me point out that `=` is shorthand for [`Set`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Set.html) and `:=` for [`SetDelayed`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/SetDelayed.html); this facilitates searching the docs. Also, as Simon Woods points out in a comment to the question, there is a [tutorial](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/TransformationRulesAndDefinitions.html#29979) on this.

## Explanation

The basic distinction is this: `y[x_]=expr` means evaluate `expr`, then whenever you see `y[something]` evaluate evaluate what resulted. On the other hand, `y[x_]:=expr` means "whenever you see `y[something]`, evaluate `expr` anew".

Here's how to see it:

```
a = 5;
y[x_] = a*x

y[3]
a = 10
y[3]
(*
15
10
15
*)
```

That is, when you define `y`, it evaluates the right hand side to `5*x` and assigns that; if you change `a` later, it never sees it. On the other hand,

```
a = 5;
f[x_] := a*x

f[3]
a = 10
f[3]
(*
15
10
30
*)
```

Compare also:

```
?? y
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

So, the value of `a` at the time of definition has been "baked in", while with `SetDelayed`, we get

```
??f
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

that is, the value of `a` at *execution time* is what will be used.

## Pitfalls

Here is an example where using `SetDelayed` results in a calculation being unnecessarily performed multiple times:

```
fsd[x_] := Integrate[z, {z, 0, x}]
gs[x_] = Integrate[z, {z, 0, x}];
```

If I try with a number, they give the same answer. But look at the `DownValues`:

```
??fsd
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
??gs
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

So, in `gs`, the integration has already been done, while in `fsd` it is performed anew every time `fsd` is evaluted. Observe:

```
t1 = Table[fsd[x], {x, 0, 1, .05}]; // AbsoluteTiming
t2 = Table[gs[x], {x, 0, 1, .05}]; // AbsoluteTiming
(*
{0.061729, Null}
{0.000061, Null}
*)
```

and `t1 == t2` evaluates to `True`. The reason for the timing differences is precisely that the symbolic integration is done every time for one, only once for the other.

Another possible pitfall is using an already-defined symbold for the right hand side. For instance, consider the difference between these:

```
ClearAll[f, g];
x = 5;
f[x_] := Sin[x];
g[x_] = Sin[x];

f[1]
g[1]
(*
Sin[1]
Sin[5]
*)
```

A simple way to avoid this is to simply use a [formal symbol](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/MathematicalAndOtherNotation.html#19606):

```
h[\[FormalX]_] = Sin[\[FormalX]]
```

which looks like this in the FrontEnd:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

## Memoization

As a final note, one may combine `Set` and `SetDelayed` to implement [memoization](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/TransformationRulesAndDefinitions.html#202640595). Here is how to calculate a Fibonacci number recursively, with

```
ClearAll[fib];
fib[1] = 1;
fib[2] = 1;
fib[n_Integer] := fib[n] = fib[n - 1] + fib[n - 2]
```

and without

```
ClearAll[fibnaive];
fibnaive[1] = 1;
fibnaive[2] = 1;
fibnaive[n_Integer] := fibnaive[n - 1] + fibnaive[n - 2]
```

memoization. The idea behind this is explained, for instance, [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/2640/16) or [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/2676/16). You can also find some elaborations [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/4654/16).

Comment: for being clear 
`y[x_]= ` : it is like one time function
`y[x_]:=` it is like normal funtion
??

Comment: +1 but please include the names `Set` and `SetDelayed` in your answer, for reference and easy searching.

Comment: Is there a difference then between y[x_]= and y[x_]:=y[x]= for caching values ?

Comment: @DSaad, no, take what acl said more literally. `y[x_]=rhs` means "evaluate the rhs to get the expression of the FUNCTION", while `y[x_]:=rhs` means that rhs is literally the expression of the function

Comment: @FaysalAberkane definately. `y[x_]=` doesn't cache any values at all

Comment: @Mr.Wizard good point, will fix it

Comment: @FaysalAberkane I am not sure I understood, but `y[x_]=Sin[x]` re-evaluates (say) `Sin[5.]` no matter how many times you say `y[5.]`. It doesn't cache values at all in this sense, while `y[x_]:=y[x]=Sin[x]` remembers that `y[5.]` is whatever it is (ie it only evaluates `Sin[5.]` once).

Comment: OK, understood.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I was explicitly trying to reduce complexity. As I mentioned nothing about localizing the symbols on the rhs earlier, I do not see how it is consistent to do it in the final section (as you know perfectly well `x = 5; y[x_] = Sin[x]` is a dangerous thing to do). But, you are correct: I should point out that the rhs is not localized.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I added a mention in the pitfalls (as it is indeed a likely tripping point).

Comment: Yes, I'm being [grouchy](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/8824/121) again, but `Clear` is about the worst way to localize, as `x` might actually be needed for something.  Much better to use `Block` or Formal Symbols.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard formal symbols it is, then :) in fact I was not familiar with these so thanks for pointing it out (I had seen you use them but had chalked it down to general perversity on your part)

Comment: lol -- yes, well, you're not the first...

Comment: @acl Does this mean that computationally pure functions can always be written with `Set` rather than `SetDelayed` as long as we use formal symbols in the definition?

Answer (score 9):

Another quick example:

I have a function:

```
f[x1_,x2_]:= x1+x1*x2
```

and I want to find it's derivative according to x2 at specific locations of x1 and x2.

```
m[x1_,x2_] = D[f[x1,x2],x2]
```

1. If you use use ":" before the "=", (Set Delay), it **evaluates the function when it is needed**, hence it will evaluate the function only when values for x1 and x2 are given.
2. The function definition without ":" before the "=" (Set) **evaluates the function before it is used** and the output is assigned to m[x1_,x2_], so if you input values in m[x1_,x2_] they are put into the **already-differentiated** equation.

If now, you would decide to put a ":" in front of the "=" for m[x1_,m2_],it will not work, since one cannot differentiate a function with respect to a numerical value (5 for example).