# How to blend some colors on a curve

Tags: list-manipulation, version-7, color

I need to define a color gradient on a 3D curve, but I'm having some problems with this.

Suppose we have a 3D curve defined as a parametric function of some real variable `phi` :

```
curve[phi_] := {...};
```

where `phi` runs from `phi1` to `phi2`.  Now, I defined the **start**, **middle** and **end** colors like this :

```
Color1 := RGBColor[0.99, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2];
Color2 := RGBColor[0.2, 0.99, 0.2, 0.8];
Color3 := RGBColor[0.2, 0.2, 0.99, 0.2];

CurveColor[phi_] = Blend[{Color1, Color2, Color3}, phi];
```

The last definition doesn't work.  I need the function `CurveColor[phi]` to output four real **positive** numbers **smaller than 1**, like this :

```
CurveColor[phi1] := {0.99, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2}
CurveColor[phi2] := {0.2, 0.2, 0.99, 0.2}
```

The colors should **blend smoothly** between `Color1` to `Color2` to `Color3`, and be uniformly distributed along the interval `phi1` to `phi2`).

So how should I define that color function ?  I don't need that function to be used in a plot3D.  I only need the color data as a list of numbers.

Please, notice that I'm working with *Mathematica 7*.

Comment: Well, yes, in the sense that I need that function to output a list of four numbers (RGB and Opacity).  The colors should be uniformly distributed on the interval phi1 to phi2 only, and blend smoothly.

Comment: Let me rephrase, are you planning on doing `ParametricPlot3D[curve ..., ColorFunction-> CurveColor]`? Or, do you just want the numbers?

Comment: I just want the numbers.  I don't need the function to be used in a plot3D.

Comment: Got it. Blending smoothly, though, is a matter of contention, though. `Blend` uses linear interpolation, so it is "smooth," but not necessarily pretty.

Comment: I think that a linear interpolation should be fine.

Comment: You should use `=` when defining `Color1`, etc. and `:=` when defining `CurveColor`.  You have it reversed.

Comment: I'd say this is a duplicate of [What is the difference between Set and SetDelayed](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/8829/what-is-the-difference-between-set-and-setdelayed), as this is the essence of the problem.

Comment: @Szabolcs not really. It has some similarities, but as the OP wants _only_ the data, it is a little different.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you only want the numbers, you can get them by using [`Apply`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Apply.html):

```
CurveColor[phi_] = List@@Blend[{Color1, Color2, Color3}, 
       Rescale[phi, {phimin, phimax}]]
```

which will ensure that you always use the same blending functionality that `Blend` uses. Note, the use of `Rescale`.

Comment: The issue is actually that he used `=` when he should have used `:=`.

Comment: @Szabolcs that is why he is getting the message, but `CurveColor` still works. So, it isn't entirely the issue.

Comment: Yes, of course for four numbers the `List@@` is important.

Comment: This solution is what I was looking for.  It's working, thanks a lot !

Comment: Why the Rescale ?

Comment: `RGBColor` only accepts values between 0 and 1. `Rescale` ensures that that is true.

Answer (score 11):

You don't `:=` constant colors.

```
Color1 = RGBColor[0.99, 0.2, 0.2, 0.5];
```

This space curve for example:

```
curve = KnotData["Trefoil", "SpaceCurve"]
(* {Sin[#1] + 2 Sin[2 #1], Cos[#1] - 2 Cos[2 #1], -Sin[3 #1]} & *)

ParametricPlot3D[curve[t], {t, 0, 2 Pi},
 PlotStyle -> AbsoluteThickness[10],
 ColorFunction -> (CurveColor[#4] &),
 ColorFunctionScaling -> True]
```

[image: pplot3d]

Since the curve loops I appended Color1 at the end for color looping.

```
CurveColor[t_] := Blend[{Color1, Color2, Color3, Color1}, t]
```

**Edit:** Color values only.

```
CurveColor[t_] := List @@ Blend[{Color1, Color2, Color3}, t]
```

Applying `List` for a list of numbers instead of a `RGBColor` expression.

```
With[{t1 = Pi, t2 = 2 Pi},
 CurveColor[(# - t1)/(t2 - t1)] & /@ Range[t1, t2, (t2 - t1)/5.]]

(* {{0.99, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2}, {0.674, 0.516, 0.2, 0.2}, *) 
(* {0.358, 0.832, 0.2, 0.2}, {0.2, 0.832, 0.358, 0.26}, *)
(* {0.2, 0.516, 0.674, 0.38}, {0.2, 0.2, 0.99, 0.5}} *)
```

Comment: This is working, but how can I extract the color data as a list ?

Comment: I was confused with the beginning. What is the point of a curve if not coloring it?

Comment: I need the color data to be exported to an ASCII file, to be used with another program.  Maybe my question wasn't clear.  The solution below is working great.

Comment: Very nice plot above, by the way !  :-)

Comment: Yes, one must supply `Blend` with values from 0 and 1. `y(x)=(x-x1)/(x2-x1)`. ;)