# How do I interpolate a set of points with colour varying along the curve?

Tags: plotting, color

I have a table with 3 columns - x position, y-position and colour.
I'd like to plot these points and join them with line segments, where the colour of the line segment is determined by 3rd variable. e.g.

```
T=Table[{n,n,n},{n,0,100}];
```

I can plot just the points like this

```
Graphics[{Hue[#3/Length[T]], Point[{#1, #2}]} & @@@ T, Frame -> True, AspectRatio -> 1]
```

How can I plot line segments instead?

Thanks!

Comment: It seems to be a duplicate but meanwhile try: `{Hue[#1[[ 3]]/Length[T]], Line[{##}[[ ;; , ;; 2]]]} & @@@ 
 Partition[T, 2, 1],`

Comment: There are 100 points and 100 colors, which color you want to apply to line between n and n+1 point? the n.?

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of [this question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/22615/)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
T = Table[{n, n, n}, {n, 0, 10}];  

Graphics[
 GraphicsComplex[
   T[[;; , ;; 2]],
   {Thickness@.02, {Hue[T[[#[[ 1]], 3]]/len], Line@#} & /@ Partition[Range[len], 2, 1] 
], Frame -> True, AspectRatio -> 1]
```

[image]

So that's another approach, but it will blur your colors:

```
len=Length @ T;

Graphics[
   GraphicsComplex[
      T[[ ;; , ;; 2]],
      {Thickness@.02, Line[Range[len], VertexColors -> (Hue[#/len] & /@ T[[ ;; , 3]])]}
                  ]
        , Frame -> True, AspectRatio -> 1]
```

[image]

---

**Edit**:

`GraphicsComplex` can be useful but for simple cases like here or the [one I've faced today](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/31207/5478) it is not a must:

```
T = Table[{n, n, n}, {n, 0, 10}];
len = Length@T;

Graphics[{Thickness@.02, 
          Line[T[[ All, {1, 2}]], 
               VertexColors -> (Hue[#/len] & /@ T[[;; , 3]])]}
        ]
```

Comment: That's perfect thanks!  I prefer the blurred one but I didn't know if it was possible.  I don't have enough reputation to upvote the answer... sorry

Answer (score 5):

If I understood you correctly, - there is a simpler way:

```
data = Table[{x, Sinc[x]}, {x, 0, 10, .5}];

ListPlot[data, 
 ColorFunction -> Hue,
 Joined -> True, 
 PlotStyle -> Thickness[.03], 
 Mesh -> All, 
 MeshStyle -> Directive[PointSize[.05], Opacity[.2]]]
```

[image]

Comment: as I understand, he'd explicilty give the color as 3rd argument of the individual points

Comment: @PinguinDirk Yeah I thought it is a possibility. Still you never know. Additionally this is good to know and ColorFunction can be custom in case he just need to specify a simple data-dependent coloring scheme.

Comment: perfectly understand- it is what I'd suggest to use too (I am too lazy to build up with primitives when there are built-in functions one could use)

Comment: Many thanks for your answer.  In reality, I need to give the colour as an extra argument.  (I have a 2D trajectory and want to use the colour to track the time taken to reach each point)

Answer (score 3):

You could also use `MeshShading`, e.g.

```
Plot[x, {x, 0, 1}, Mesh -> {Range[0, 1, 0.01]}, 
 MeshShading -> Hue /@ Range[0, 1, 0.01], MeshStyle -> None, 
 Frame -> True]
Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, Mesh -> {Range[-1, 1, 0.1]}, 
 MeshFunctions -> (#2 &), 
 MeshShading -> (Hue[Rescale[#, {-1, 1}]] & /@ Range[-1, 1, 0.1]), 
 MeshStyle -> None, Frame -> True]
Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, MeshFunctions -> (#2 &), 
 Mesh -> {Range[-1, 1, 0.1]}, 
 MeshShading -> (Hue[Abs@#] & /@ Range[-1, 1, 0.1]), 
 MeshStyle -> None, Frame -> True]
```

(in first plot domain and range same so did not need`MeshFunctions`)
[image]

Illustrating arbitrary list of points (and line segments) and color function based on third variable:

```
dat = Table[{j, RandomReal[], RandomReal[{0, 10}]}, {j, 100}];
if = Interpolation[dat[[All, {1, 2}]], InterpolationOrder -> 1];
Plot[if[x], {x, 1, 10}, MeshFunctions -> (#2 &), 
 Mesh -> {dat[[All, 2]]}, 
 MeshShading -> (Hue[Rescale[#, {0, 10}]] & /@ dat[[All, 3]]), 
 MeshStyle -> None, Frame -> True]
```

[image]