# Color gradient varying in a path

Tags: color, generative-art

The code below is to create something like a logo. I want to apply a color gradient over the polygons of the pattern, but they vary along the path. The image that I want to approach is this:

[image]

```
ang = 66 Degree; h = 70; esp = 20.5;
p1 = {0, 0};
p2 = {h/Tan[ang], h};
p3 = {p2[[1]] + esp/Sin[ang], h};
p4 = {p1[[1]] + esp/Sin[ang], 0};
shift = {p3[[1]] - esp, 0};
rectangle = Polygon[{{0, 0}, {esp, 0}, {esp, h}, {0, h}}];
parallelogram = Polygon[{p1, p2, p3, p4}];
parallelogram2 = GeometricTransformation[
   parallelogram,
       { 
        {{1, 0}, {0, -1}}, 
        {0, h} + {p2[[1]], 0} + 4 shift
        }
       ];
Graphics[
 {
  EdgeForm[{Thick, Black}], FaceForm[Gray],
  Table[Translate[rectangle, i shift], {i, 1, 4}],
  parallelogram2,
  EdgeForm[{Thick, Black}], FaceForm[White],
  Table[Translate[parallelogram, i shift], {i, 0, 4}]
  }
 ]
```

> [image]

I believe the [Blend function](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Blend.html) is the best option, but I do not understand how to apply it ...

**EDIT**

I liked [KennyColnago's solution](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/151993/37895), but I'm still looking for something closer to the image.

In an attempt to approach the solution I tried at least to define the four colors of each corner of the polygons. Below the pixels of the first polygon ...

```
g1 = {{3, 2}, {50, 2}, {74, 155}, {117, 155}};
```

[image]

That way I got all 20 pixels. Four pixels for each of the five front polygons ...

```
corners = 4;
g1 = {{3, 2}, {50, 2}, {74, 155}, {117, 155}};

img = Import[
   "C:\\Users\\Leandro\\Desktop\\Image.png"];

Map[RGBColor, 
 Map[PixelValue[img, #] &, 
  NestList[Plus[# + Table[{71, 0}, corners]] &, g1, 
   corners], {2}], {2}]
```

[image]

Comment: related: [31131](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/31131/5478), [6562](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/6562/5478)

Comment: @Kuba The [RoundedBlock](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/138720/37895) function approaches the link because it has the idea of shadow ...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I like the dimensionality suggested by `VertexColors`. Given your definitions of `ang` ... `parallelogram2`, I tried variations of colour schemes such as the following.

```
Graphics[{
   EdgeForm[{Thick, Black}],
   Table[
      Translate[rectangle, i*shift] /. 
         Polygon[x_List] :> 
           Polygon[x, VertexColors -> 
              Map[ColorData["SolarColors", #] &, Range[i/6, 0, -i/12]]],
      {i, 1, 4}],
   {parallelogram2 /. 
       Polygon[x_List] :> 
          Polygon[x, VertexColors -> 
             Table[Lighter[ColorData["RoseColors", k], 0.7],
                {k, {0.35, 0.57, 0.78, 1.}}]]},
   Table[
      Translate[parallelogram, i*shift] /. 
         Polygon[x_List] :> 
            Polygon[x, VertexColors -> 
               Map[Lighter[ColorData["RoseColors", #], i/6] &, 
                   Range[0.7 - i*0.05, 1, (0.3 + i*0.05)/3]]],
      {i, 0, 4}]
}]
```

[image: logo with VertexColors]

Comment: Are coming. The shadow is fundamental ...

Comment: Today I finished my activities, but on 24.07 I will resume analyzing the colors of the drawing through Photoshop. It would be better through Mathematica, but I still do not have the ability ...

Answer (score 6):

```
col = Table[Blend[{RGBColor[1, 0, 0, 1], RGBColor[0, 1, 0, 0]}, x], {x, 0, 1, 1/11}];

Graphics[{
  EdgeForm[{Thick, Black}],
  Table[{FaceForm[col[[2 n - 1]]], Translate[rectangle, n shift]}, {n,1, 4}],
  Table[{FaceForm[col[[2 n]]], Translate[parallelogram, (n - 1) shift]}, {n, 1, 5}],
  {FaceForm[col[[11]]], parallelogram2}}]
```

[image]