# How to vary color of a graphics primitive?

Tags: graphics, color

I would like to be able to vary color of a graphics primitive. For starters, varying color of a `Line` object along it's length would be sufficient. For example, if I have a `ColorDataFunction` function `f`,  the first point of the the line, the color would be `f[0]` and the last point `f[1]`. Or something similar. The only idea I got was to take `ColorData[myScheme, "Image"]` and transform it as needed or somehow exploit a `ParametricPlot`. But this both seems really clumsy. Is there a better way? Essentially, I would like something equivalent to adding a `ColorFunction`-like parameter to `Graphics`.

Comment: What about [31131](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/31131/5478)

Comment: It seems that at least for `Line`, the `VertexColors` parameter does what I need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use VertexColors like @Kuba said:

[image]