# Time ColorFunction

Tags: color

I have the following data

```
data = {{0, 0}, {-0.0385, 0.0667}, {-0.0566, 0.1283}, {0.0966, 
    0.0441}, {-0.1166, 
    0.0038}, {-0.2046, -0.0673}, {-0.2536, -0.21}, {-0.5485, \
-0.2643}, {-0.3702, -0.1148}, {-0.4201, -0.2319}, {-0.5558, -0.2748}, \
{-0.693, -0.3272}, {-0.6276, -0.3844}, {-0.6305, -0.3448}, {-0.671, \
-0.4833}, {-0.6809, -0.3441}, {-0.7082, -0.2548}, {-0.5978, -0.3126}, \
{-0.4337, -0.3588}, {-0.2542, -0.4139}, {-0.3318, -0.3318}, {-0.4991, \
-0.2123}, {-0.4195, -0.1966}, {-0.4797, 0.0285}, {-0.2198, 
    0.0965}, {-0.1914, 0.1604}, {-0.0854, 0.1668}, {0.0715, 
    0.3025}, {0.0847, 0.3116}, {0.175, 0.3152}, {0.0123, 
    0.4577}, {0.0941, 0.4445}, {0.083, 0.3729}, {0.1251, 
    0.1414}, {0.0239, 0.3119}, {-0.0665, 0.3748}, {-0.0171, 
    0.4261}, {0.0781, 0.4031}, {-0.0945, 0.315}, {-0.2497, 
    0.3892}, {-0.285, 0.3823}, {-0.2873, 0.4343}, {-0.196, 
    0.4628}, {-0.2812, 0.5166}, {-0.186, 0.2917}, {-0.3101, 
    0.3047}, {-0.4103, 0.2439}, {-0.4335, 0.2251}, {-0.5113, 
    0.4149}, {-0.6487, 0.4662}, {-0.5045, 0.1807}};
```

which represents movement of some particle in time 0,...,50.

Using `ColorFunction` is possible to get rainbow color according to axis $y$ as

```
ListLinePlot[data,ColorFunction->Function[{x,y},ColorData["Rainbow"][y]],PlotStyle->Thick]
```

or axis $x$ as

```
ListLinePlot[data,ColorFunction->Function[{x,y},ColorData["Rainbow"][x]],PlotStyle->Thick]
```

Is it possible to use `ColorFunction` according to time 0,...,50 and to get rainbow according to its movement in this time?

Comment: It this a duplicate? [How to blend colors on a curve?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/22615/5478)

Comment: Also [related](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/31131/5478)

Comment: Time example I posted (0,...,50) just means that there is 51 steps in order {0,0},....,{-0.5045,0.1807} from data.I would like to redistribute the rainbow color according to the order of the points (which could be understood as a time). Not just by individual axes.

Comment: colloring according to axis y would be: http://img266.imageshack.us/img266/8488/5gc.png
and according to x: http://img716.imageshack.us/img716/7307/xpt.png
But what I need is according to order of points. It means the first point is purple/blue and rainbow continue on following points and red colour is at last points.

Comment: `Graphics[{Thick,
  Line[data, 
   VertexColors -> 
    Array[Blend["Rainbow", #/Length@data] &, Length@data]]
  }]`

Comment: Thanks a lot. This was exactly what was I looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that the links that I've provided are closely related but not duplicates. I decided to write this answer but I will add an extension which may be useful for others.

This is what OP finds well suited to his needs:

```
Graphics[{Thick, 
         Line[data, 
              VertexColors -> Array[Blend["Rainbow", #/Length@data] &, Length@data]]}]
```

However one may want to blend the palette along the lines but **scalled with path** not with **number of vertex** as in the former example.

```
path = {0} ~ Join ~ Accumulate[EuclideanDistance @@@ Partition[data, 2, 1]];

Graphics[{Thick, 
     Line[data, 
     VertexColors -> Array[Blend["Rainbow", path[[#]]/Last@path] &, Length@data]]}]
```