# Defining a function in terms of matrix elements

Tags: functions, matrix, evaluation

Currently trying to use elements from a matrix in defining a function however having some trouble. This is a somewhat simplified version of the problem.

Say I have the matrix

```
m={{Sin[x],Cos[x]},{Tan[x],ArcTan[x]}}
```

And I want to define a function in terms of the first element. How would I go about doing this ? 
Have tried

```
f[x_]:=m[[1,1,1]]
```

This seems to work until I try and evaluate it for a value of x.Then it just returns Sin[x].

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: `m = {{Sin[x], Cos[X]}, {Tan[x], ArcTan[x]}};
f[x_] := Evaluate@m[[1, 1]]; f[Pi]`

Comment: Thanks, now got it working. Although I needed to use m[[1,1,1]] to get the first element from the matrix. m[[1,1]] returns the first row.

Comment: I now understand why. It is because I have it in matrix form.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `Set` instead of `SetDelayed`.  Please see here for an explanation of the difference: [What is the difference between Set and SetDelayed?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/8829/what-is-the-difference-between-set-and-setdelayed)

First make sure that `x` has no value assigned.  Then you can do

```
In[1]:= m = {{Sin[x], Cos[x]}, {Tan[x], ArcTan[x]}}
Out[1]= {{Sin[x], Cos[x]}, {Tan[x], ArcTan[x]}}

In[2]:= f[x_] = m[[1, 1]]
Out[2]= Sin[x]

In[3]:= f[1]
Out[3]= Sin[1]
```

Answer (score 1):

One approach is this:

```
m = {{Sin[x], Cos[x]}, {Tan[x], ArcTan[x]}}
f[y_] := m[[1, 1]] /. x -> y

f[a]  -> Sin[a]
```

another:

```
m[x_] = {{Sin[x], Cos[x]}, {Tan[x], ArcTan[x]}}
f[y_] := m[y][[1, 1]] 

f[b]  -> Sin[b]
```