# How to substitue local variables into expression with free variables?

Tags: function-construction, replacement

I'm wondering how to do the following:

```
    expr = L + R;

    foo[L_, R_] := expr;

    foo[1, 2]


(* L + R *)
```

and have it substitute the function variables into the expression. I realize that I could create dummy variables and do it like

```
foo[l_, r_] := expr /. L->l /. R->r
```

but my actual expression has a lot of free variables, and so I would like to know if there is a simpler way.

Comment: Check out `Evaluate`.

Comment: foo[L_,R_]=expr;  The := is delayed evaluation which is usually correct but not in this precise case.

Comment: Use `=` instead of `:=`.  It's not necessary to `Evaluate` IMO because it would be completely equivalent to just using `=`.  I'd consider this question a duplicate of [What is the difference between Set and SetDelayed?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/8829/what-is-the-difference-between-set-and-setdelayed).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in the comments, use `Set` (`=`) instead of `SetDelayed` (`:=`) while making sure that `L` and `R` have no value assigned:

```
expr = L+R
foo[L_, R_] = expr

foo[1, 2]
(* ==> 3 *)
```

Comment: I went ahead and changed this, since it was community wiki.  I think Evaluate would be completely equivalent to just using `Set` here.  Hope you don't mind, please check the edit.

Comment: @Szabolcs Sure, even if these were not CW I welcome good edits:)