# How to localize symbols on the right-hand side of Rule when using ReplaceAll?

Tags: evaluation, pattern-matching, variable-definitions, scoping, localization

I am frustrated by the following:

```
{1, 2, 3.0} /. a_Integer -> a + 1
```

The `a` on the left side of the arrow is localized and appears in green whereas its sibling on the right side is blue. Consequently, I have to write:

```
Block[{a}, {1, 2, 3.0} /. a_Integer -> a + 1]
```

to avoid naming conflicts.

It doesn't make sense to me that, within one inbuilt function, a variable is treated differently. I already got some hard to find errors because I forgot to block.

What did I overlook here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this case you need to use `:>` instead of `->`:

```
{1, 2, 3.0} /. a_Integer :> a + 1
```

This will ensure effective localization.

Refereces:

- [`Rule`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Rule.html) and [`RuleDelayed`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/RuleDelayed.html)
- [Immediate and Delayed Definitions](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/ImmediateAndDelayedDefinitions.html)
- [What is the difference between Set and SetDelayed?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/8829/what-is-the-difference-between-set-and-setdelayed)

Comment: Of course. I put my question as answered. Thank you very much.

Comment: @eldo Even though it is about the basics, this is a good question because it is very clear and to the point.  I changed the title a bit to make it even more clear, in hope of making it useful for future visitors.

Comment: Georg Cantor once remarked "In mathematics the art of proposing a question must be held of higher value than solving it." Looking at your simple :> I would say: "In mathematics the art of proposing an answer must be held of higher value than the underlying question."