# Having variables appear aqua in user defined function

Tags: front-end, function-construction, color, syntax-highlighting

In many of the inbuilt mathematica function, variables appear aqua like in:

[image]

However, when creating your own function, variables no longer have that green coloring and are instead colored like an undefined variable

[image]

Is there any way to define functions so that variables used in arguments like in the manner above can get the aqua syntax coloring?

Comment: you can set this via the preferences panel, the options inspector or a stylesheet. All of these methods have been discussed on this site.

Comment: @MikeHoneychurch That has to due with changing the syntax highlight coloring itself. I am asking how to get variables used in arguments of user-defined functions to exhibit that syntax coloring.

Comment: ok. misunderstood. @acl has your answer

Comment: @MikeHoneychurch looks like a duplicate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`SyntaxInformation`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SyntaxInformation.html). In this case,

```
SyntaxInformation[Lim] = {"ArgumentsPattern" -> {_, _, OptionsPattern[]}, 
   "LocalVariables" -> {"Limit", {2}}}
```

does what you want.

Comment: I also have another function `ImplicitPlot[p_, q_, r_] := ContourPlot[p, q, r]` and I tried doing something similar: `SyntaxInformation[ImplicitPlot] := {"ArgumentsPattern" -> {_, _, _, OptionsPattern[]},  "LocalVariables" -> {"Plot", {2, 3}}}` but it's not working for this one... any idea why?

Comment: I'll take a look in a few hours if nobody else does so by then. Away from mathematica right now.

Comment: Do `SyntaxInformation[implicitPlot] ={"ArgumentsPattern" -> {_, _, _, OptionsPattern[]}, "LocalVariables" -> {"Plot", {2, 3}}}` and does work. Make sure you use `Set` (`=`) and not `SetDelayed` `:=` ! I searched for an explanation of the difference and found [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/8831/16) which, to my surprise, I wrote myself.