# How do I make my function behave more like Plot?

Tags: syntax-highlighting, optional-arguments

I have written a function `Fun` as below:

```
Fun[x_Symbol, xrange_, imageSize_, axeslabel_] :=
 Plot[x^2, {x, xrange[[1]], xrange[[2]]}, 
   ImageSize -> imageSize, 
   AxesLabel -> axeslabel]

Fun[x, {-1, 2}, 400, {"x", "y"}]
```

[image]

However, I'd like to rewrite it to use `OptionsPattern`

```
RewriteFun[x_Symbol, OptionsPattern[Plot]] := 
  Plot[x^2, {x, -1, 2}, 
    ImageSize -> OptionValue[ImageSize], 
    AxesLabel -> OptionValue[AxesLabel]]

RewriteFun[x, ImageSize -> 400, AxesLabel -> {"x", "y"}]
```

[image]

I have two problems.

- I don't know how to deal with an option like `{x, xmin, xmax}`.
- I don't how to get the kind of syntax coloring the varible `x` has in `Plot[x^2, {x, -1, 2}]`.

[image]

So my question is: How do I revise the `RewriteFun` to solve my problems?

Comment: An argument of the form `{x, xmin, xmax}` isn't a option for `Plot`. It is `Plot`'s ***required*** second argument. You must add a required second argument to your function to handle it.

Comment: (1) See [1446](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1446) and [54956](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/54956).  (2) Presumably you mean the **argument** `{x, xmin, xmax}`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's my interpretation of the question:

```
ClearAll[RewriteFun];
SetAttributes[RewriteFun, HoldAll];
Options[RewriteFun] = Options[Plot];
SyntaxInformation[
   RewriteFun] = {"ArgumentsPattern" -> {{_, _, _}, 
     OptionsPattern[Plot]}, "LocalVariables" -> {"Plot", {1}}};
RewriteFun[dom : {x_, _, _}, OptionsPattern[]] := 
 Plot[x^2, dom, ImageSize -> OptionValue[ImageSize], 
  AxesLabel -> OptionValue[AxesLabel]]

RewriteFun[{t, -2, 1}, ImageSize -> 150, AxesLabel -> {"x", "y"}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 2):

You could do the following:

```
Options[fun] = {ImageSize -> 400, AxesLabel -> {"x", "y"}, xmin -> -1, xmax -> 2};

fun[x_Symbol, OptionsPattern[]] :=
 Plot[x^2, {x, OptionValue@xmin, OptionValue@xmax}, 
  ImageSize -> OptionValue@ImageSize, 
  AxesLabel -> OptionValue@AxesLabel]

fun[z, xmin -> -2, AxesLabel -> {"z", "y"}]
```

[image]

You could even turn the symbol (or the whole function) into an option:

```
Options[fun] = {ImageSize -> 400, AxesLabel -> {"x", "y"}, symbol -> x, xmin -> -1, xmax -> 2};

fun[OptionsPattern[]] :=
 Block[{sym = OptionValue@symbol},
  Plot[sym^2, {sym, OptionValue@xmin, OptionValue@xmax},
   ImageSize -> OptionValue@ImageSize,
   AxesLabel -> OptionValue@AxesLabel]]
```

Comment: @Öskå Quotation: "I don't know how to deal with an option like {x, xmin, xmax}."