# Define function over expression

Tags: functions

Suppose I have the following expression

```
system = x + y + z
```

And I would like to define a function that contains this function, without explicitly typing the right hand side of the above equation.

I tried:

```
systemfunction = Function[{x,y,z},system]
```

but this does not produce the desired result as the following evaluation yields:

```
systemfunction[1,1,1]
```

> (x + y + z)[1,1,1]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
systemFunction[x_, y_, z_] = system
```

Note the use of `=` instead of `:=` and see [What is the difference between Set and SetDelayed?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/8829/what-is-the-difference-between-set-and-setdelayed)

Answer (score 2):

The problem you face here is that `Function` does not evaluate your `system` variable. It takes it as it is without making the transformation of `system` -> `x+y+z`. You can see this in the output directly:

```
Function[{x, y, z}, system]
(* Function[{x, y, z}, system] *)
```

This comes from how `Function` treats its arguments. You can prevent this by temporary using another function (here `List`) which doesn't make this and then replacing the `List` with `Functions`:

```
system = x + y + z;
systemFunction = Function @@ {{x, y, z}, system}
```

Now `systemFunction[1, 1, 1]` gives 3 as expected.

Please note, that this is only one (and not the best) way to do it. To understand how all this works in *Mathematica* you should read about Attributes, HoldAll and injecting code. If you don't find anything searching this site, I'm sure we can collect some useful links.