# Integrating the second derivative of a 3D curve

Tags: vector-calculus

I have a 3D curve

```
K2[s_] := 
c1[s] + 0.4*(j[s]*Sin[500*Pi*s/97.8] - v[s]*Cos [500*Pi*s/97.8])
```

where j and v are frame vectors.

I want to find the integral of the squared second derivative of the curve with respect to parameter s, from 0 to 5.

```
h[s_] := D[D[K2[s], s], s]

NIntegrate[(h[s])^2, {s, 0, 5}]
```

takes too long and gives;

```
The integrand (<<6>>+0.4` (<<1>>))^2 has evaluated to non-numerical \
values for all sampling points in the region with boundaries \
{{0,5`}}. >
```

Where do I do wrong? Should I use numerical derivatives?

Thank you.

Comment: Does `K2[s]` evaluate to a numerical value within the region `{s,0,5}`?

Comment: I checked but no, however I can plot the function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's try to simplify your question. I don't have the definitions for `c1`, `j` and `v`, so I'll just use:

```
K2[s_] := s^3
```

and

```
h[s_] := D[D[K2[s], s], s]
```

(you could also write `D[k2[s], {s, 2}]`, to get the second derivative, but that's probably a matter of taste.)

Now if you evaluate:

```
h[2.]
```

you get the strange result:

> D[D[8., 2.], 2.]

and the error message:

> General::ivar: 2.` is not a valid variable. >>

To understand this, [you have to understand how `:=` (`SetDelayed`) works](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/8829/what-is-the-difference-between-set-and-setdelayed). In a nutshell: `h[s_] := ...` basically means "whenever you see the pattern h[*something*], take this expression, replace `s` with *something* and evaluate the whole thing. So `h[2.]` first evaluates to:

```
D[D[K2[2.], 2.], 2.]
```

And now the error message makes sense: You can't derive some expression by `2.`, because `2.` is not a variable.

The easiest way around this is to use `Set` instead of `SetDelayed`, which evaluates the symbolic derivative on the right hand side, *then* assigns it to `h[s]`:

```
h[s_] = D[D[K2[s], s], s]
```