# How can I access a variable using Position?

Tags: expression-manipulation

I want to define a vector `PosVec[a, b]` dependent on the variables `a` and `b` of a matrix `VecMat[a, b]`. I want to calculate the "positions" in `VecMat[a, b]` of the maximum values in `VecMatQ[a, b]` and store them in `PosVec[a, b]` .

My problem is that, with my code below, I can't access the variables `a` and `b` of `PosVec` by `PosVec[a, b] -> PosVec[1, 1]` For the positions in `VecMatQ` where there are entries of `a` and `b`, `Position` generates empty spaces as shown below:

Here is my code:

```
Remove["Global`*"]

m = {{1, -a + b, 3}, {b, -6, 4}, {3, b, 0}};

VecMat[a_, b_] = Eigenvectors[m];

VecMatQ[a_, b_] = VecMat[a, b]*Conjugate[VecMat[a, b]];

PosVec[a_, b_] = 
  Table[Position[VecMatQ[a, b][[i]], Max[VecMat[a, b][[i]]]], {i, 1, 3}] // Flatten;

PosVec[1, 1]
```

> `{{},{},{}}`

but

```
Table[Position[VecMatQ[1, 1][[i]], Max[VecMat[1, 1][[i]]]], {i, 1, 3}] // Flatten
```

gives the right values

> `{(3),(2),(1)}`

Can someone help me to make the evaluation of `Position` dependent on the variables `a` and `b`?

Comment: Shortest way: change `PosVec[a_, b_] =` to `PosVec[a_, b_] :=`, i.e. use `SetDelayed` instead of `Set`. Longest (but cleaner I think) way: change all `Set` to `SetDelayed`, define `m` as a two-args function, and modify the right-hand side of your second definition accordingly.

Comment: Is it essential if I define m as two arg function or I do it after calculation of Eigenvectors?

Comment: I think it depends on what you are doing. I would recommend in any case using `SetDelayed` instead of `Set` when for instance a definition involves parameters (so regarding `m`, defining it as `m := {{1, -a + b, 3}, {b, -6, 4}, {3, b, 0}}`). If `a` and `b` were to have values before defining `m`, the definition of `m` won't be affected, which is not the case when using a `Set`.

Comment: Probably of interest about `Set` and `SetDelayed` is [this post](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/8829/what-is-the-difference-between-set-and-setdelayed).

Answer (score 1):

Shortest way: change PosVec[a_, b_] = to PosVec[a_, b_] :=, i.e. use SetDelayed instead of Set. Longest (but cleaner I think) way: change all Set to SetDelayed, define m as a two-args function, and modify the right-hand side of your second definition accordingly. – Xavier 19 hours ago

Yes that works thx!