# FindRoot for numerical calculation of integral equation with parameters

Tags: equation-solving, numerical-integration

I have a problem with a calculation. I was not able to find a corresponding answer. I try to find a numerical calculation of a integral equation with parameters. 
In general I understand how to solve a simple problem if there isn't a integral. For example:

```
yy[a_, b_] := x^2 - a + b
gg[a_, b_] := x /. FindRoot[yy[a, b] == 0, {x, 1}]
gg[3, 1]
1.41421
```

[image]
It works with warning in more complicated examples:

```
 Veffd2i[m_, T_] := 
 4 - ((2 E^(-((m + Sqrt[4 + M^2])/
       T)) )/((1 + E^(-((m + Sqrt[M^2 + 4])/T))) T \[Sqrt](4 + M)^2))
Veffd2i2[m_, T_] := M /. FindRoot[Veffd2i[m, T] == 0, {M, 0}]
Veffd2i2[1, -2]
```

> The line search decreased the step size to within tolerance specified \
>   by AccuracyGoal and PrecisionGoal but was unable to find a sufficient \
>   decrease in the merit function. You may need more than \
>   MachinePrecision digits of working precision to meet these tolerances.

```
24992.6
```

But if I want to add a integration in my example, I face with the next one:

```
Veffd2i[m_?NumberQ, T_?NumberQ] := 
 4 + Integrate[-((
    2 E^(-((m + Sqrt[4 + (l + M)^2])/T))
      l^2)/((1 + E^(-((m + Sqrt[(l + M)^2 + 4])/T))) T Sqrt[
     4 + (l + M)^2])), {l, -100, 100}]
Veffd2i2[m_?NumberQ, T_?NumberQ] := 
 M /. FindRoot[Veffd2i[m, T] == 0, {M, 0}]
Veffd2i2[1, -2]
```

And, Mathematica doesn't want to calculate more simple integral:

```
yyy[a_?NumberQ,b_?NumberQ]:=Integrate[E^(-E^(a+U^2+x)),{x,-1,0}]+b
ggg[a_?NumberQ, b_?NumberQ] := U /. FindRoot[yyy[a, b] == 0, {U, 0.1}]
ggg[1, -2]
```

> FindRoot::nlnum: The function value {Undefined} is not a list of numbers with dimensions {1} at {U} = {0.1}.
>   ReplaceAll::reps: {FindRoot[yyy[1,-2]==0,{U,0.1}]} is neither a list of replacement rules nor a valid dispatch table, and so cannot be used for replacing.

And I'd like to ask about is it possible to automatize process? That is if I will want to calculate thousand point: Veffd2i2[0,0], Veffd2i2[0,1], Veffd2i2[1, 0], ...  rather than one point.

Comment: Does replacing `Integrate` with `NIntegrate` in your code produces results you want/like?

Comment: What's the value of `l` and `M`? Are they syntaxic errors ?

Comment: @AntonAntonov   replacing Integrate with NIntegrate leads to greater  numbers of  errors

Comment: @Valacar  I updated the question, there was "l" in the second example. It was the mistake. In second example I want to obtain a dependence "M" on "m" and "T".

Comment: For `yyy`, use `Integrate[E^(-E^(a + U^2 + x)), {x, -1, 0}, Assumptions -> {a, U} \[Element] Reals]`, or perhaps `Integrate[E^(-E^(a + U^2 + x)), {x, -1, 0}, 
 GenerateConditions -> False]`; also, to save time, use `=` instead of `:=`.

Comment: Also, in general, make the parameters in your function expressions arguments of the functions. It makes dealing with numeric functions easier, aside from being good programming practice.  E.g. `Veffd2i[m_?NumberQ, T_?NumberQ, M_?NumberQ] :=...` (when using `NIntegrate` as Anton recommended) eliminates the `NIntegrate` errors one otherwise gets.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Thank you! What you mean by "save time, use `=` instead of `:=` " the calculated time? And do you know why if I write `Assumptions -> {a, U}` in last example, Mathematica tells that it is "Unknown option Assumptions in NIntegrate..."?

Comment: (1) [The basic difference between `Set`/`=` and `SetDelayed`/`:=`](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/8829/what-is-the-difference-between-set-and-setdelayed) is that `=` evaluated the RHS (your `Integrate`, for instance) once and for all time when the definition is made; whereas `:=` will evaluate the RHS every time the function is invoked (see link). So with `:=` you reevaluate the integral every time, which is a time-consuming operation. Since the general integral can be found, it will be faster to do it only once....

Comment: ...(2) `NIntegrate` does not have an option `Assumptions` (but `Integrate` does). In general, numerical functions will not have an `Assumptions` option because such problems are numerically explicit/definite. Symbolic functions sometimes have the option `Assumptions` for giving assumptions about symbolic parameters.

Answer (score 2):

From the comments:

> > replacing Integrate with NIntegrate leads to greater numbers of errors

Here is how it is done:

```
In[67]:= ClearAll["Veffd2i*"]
Veffd2i[M_?NumberQ, m_?NumberQ, T_?NumberQ] := 
  4 + NIntegrate[-((2 E^(-((m + Sqrt[4 + (l + M)^2])/T)) l^2)/((1 + 
           E^(-((m + Sqrt[(l + M)^2 + 4])/T))) T Sqrt[
          4 + (l + M)^2])), {l, -100, 100}, 
    Method -> {"GlobalAdaptive", "SymbolicProcessing" -> 0}];
Veffd2i2[m_?NumberQ, T_?NumberQ] := 
 M /. FindRoot[Veffd2i[M, m, T] == 0, {M, 0}]
Veffd2i2[1, -2]

Out[70]= -2.14841*10^-12

In[71]:= res = Table[Veffd2i2[i, j], {i, 0, 10}, {j, 0, 10}];

In[72]:= Chop[Map[# /. {x_ /; (! NumberQ[x]) :> 0} &, res, {2}]]

Out[72]= {{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1.69524, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, -2.85528, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 
  0, -1.69382, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 2.77715, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
   0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, -3.78568, -1.28138, 1.16415*10^-10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 3.44355, 0, 0, 
  0, 0, 0, 1.16414*10^-10}, {0, 0, 0, 7.33208, 0, 1.92166, 0, 0, 0, 0,
   0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, -26.4683, 0, 
  0, -3.87403, -0.631233, 1.16357*10^-10, 0, 0, 0}}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for answer. I'd like to ask you about the initial approximation. When one uses FindRoot, then one needs to know about the initial approximation for `U`. And it is the nontrivial approximation: if for an equation without an integral I can plot a graph and know about initial approxiation, then for an integral equation I cannot plot a graph. It turns out that I must select `U` by hand. Can Mathematica help me in this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Many questions with a basic problem: Do the equations have roots that FindRoot can find? The plot of your first example shows, there is no root.

```
Veffd2i[m_, T_] = 
 4 - ((2 E^(-((m + Sqrt[4 + M^2])/T)))/((1 + E^(-((m + Sqrt[M^2 + 4])/T))) T \[Sqrt](4 + M)^2)) // Simplify

Limit[Veffd2i[1, -2], M -> ∞]
{4}

Plot[Veffd2i[1, -2], {M, -100000, 100000}]
```

[image]

In your 2. example is "l" undefined.

Comment: I appologize for the mistake. In reality there needs `-4-…` instead of `4-…`