# Why doesn't this integral evaluate the laplace transform

Tags: integral-transforms

I want to evaluate the laplace transform using "Integrate" rather than "LaplaceTransform". However, for some reason the two don't give the same output.

I want to do

```
F[s_] := Integrate[E^(-s*t)*f[t], {t, 0, Infinity}]
```

Instead of

```
F[s_] := LaplaceTransform[f[t], t, s]
```

However, it gives me the following error:

> Integrate::ilim: Invalid integration variable or limit(s) in
>   {0.000102143,0,[Infinity]}. >>

What am I doing wrong?

ps. here is my complete code:

```
ClearAll[t, s, f, F, T]
k0 = 0.01;
g = 1;
k[t_] := 1/(1 + (1/k0 - 1)*E^(-g*t))
f[t_] := (1/3) (k[t])^(-2/3)


F[s_] := Integrate[E^(-s*t)*f[t], {t, 0, Infinity}]
Plot[{f[t], F[t]}, {t, 0.01, 5}]
```

---

The above code works now, but when I add an "NSolve" line, I get a similar problem:

```
F[s_, T_] := Block[{t}, NIntegrate[E^(-s*t)*f[t], {t, T, Infinity}]]
iir[t_] := NSolve[F[s, t] == 1, s]


Plot[{iir[x]}, {x, 0.01, 5}]
```

This gives the following error:

```
NIntegrate::inumr: "The integrand E^(-s\t)/(3\(1/(1+99. E^-t))^(2/3)) has evaluated to non-numerical values for all sampling points in the region with boundaries {{\[Infinity],0.0101019}}. \!\(\*ButtonBox[\">>\",
Appearance->{Automatic, None},
BaseStyle->\"Link\",
ButtonData:>\"paclet:ref/message/NIntegrate/inumr\",
ButtonNote->\"NIntegrate::inumr\"]\)"
```

Comment: I think `t` has a value. Use `Clear[t]` or restart your kernel (`Quit[]`).

Comment: I already did ClearAll[t]. Changing to Clear[t] doesn't help...

Comment: You need to show a complete (but minimal) example, otherwise the question will get closed as not being answerable due to insufficient information.  We need code that we can copy without modifications, evaluate in a newly started Mathematica session, and immediately see the problem.

Comment: I've added the complete code

Comment: `t` is given a value by `Plot`.  Use a different variable, or localize `t` within `F` through `Block`.  That said, `Integrate` should not be used with inexact values (i.e. anything that has a decimal point in it).  Compute the integral *first*, ensuring exact values only.  Add `Assumptions` when necessary, e.g. `s>0`.  Then take that result, assign it to a function, and plot it.  Here you are re-computing the integral for every single argument value, and also risking problems due to inexact values.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't know about the fact that the $t$ variable is interpreted as the same in those two lines. It works now, but very slowly, probaby because it is recalculating the integral every time, like you said. How do I assign it to a function rather than recalculating every time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem happens because `Plot` temporarily assigns a value to `t`.  `t` is used within `F` without any localization (such as `Block`).  This breaks things.

I suggest you avoid using inexact numbers with `Integrate`. It is known to cause problems sometimes. I also suggest not to re-compute the integral for every argument value of `F`.  Compute it *once*, then use the result.  This also eliminates `t` from the definition of `F`, and avoids this problem you see.

```
ClearAll[t, s, f, F, T, g, k0]
g = 1;
k[t_] := 1/(1 + (1/k0 - 1)*E^(-g*t))
f[t_] := (1/3) (k[t])^(-2/3)

F[s_] = 
 Integrate[E^(-s*t)*f[t], {t, 0, Infinity}, 
  Assumptions -> (k0 > 0 && s > 0)]
(* Hypergeometric2F1[-(2/3), s, 1 + s, (-1 + k0)/k0]/(3 s) *)

k0 = 0.01;

Plot[{f[t], F[t]}, {t, 0.01, 5}]
```

Notice that I used `=` instead of `:=`.  Please see:

- [What is the difference between Set and SetDelayed?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/8829/what-is-the-difference-between-set-and-setdelayed)

Comment: If I use NIntegrate instead, is it still advisable to use = instead of :=?

Comment: @Programmer2134 You should understand the difference between `=` and `:=`.  I included a link to an explanation.  If you understand the difference, it will be clear that using `=` will lead to an error due to symbols being used in the integrand.

Comment: Sorry. I understood = and := in the abstract I think, but didn't make the connection. However, I'm still confused. I've read the entire = vs := tutorial, but I get an error that shouldn't happen if I understand it correctly (therefore I must still misunderstand it...). I've added the code in the main question.