# problem with (numerical) integration

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

The (simplified) matrix I use is the following:

```
H[t_] := {{34, 
 Piecewise[{{0, t < 3.4}, {0.7*(t - 3.4), 
  t >= 3.4}}]}, {Piecewise[{{0, t < 3.4}, {0.7*(t - 3.4), 
  t >= 3.4}}], 1}}
```

and the eigenvalues are:

```
v[t_] := Eigenvalues[H[t]];
```

I want to integrate (numerically) the eigenvalues, but the result is wrong. I found out that the problem is:

```
v[t] /. t -> 1 gives {1, 34}

v[1] gives {34, 1}
```

Can anyone help me solve this problem ? In fact I have to evaluate the integral of the eigenvalues of a 12x12 matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation of [`Eigenvalues`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Eigenvalues.html):

> If they are numeric, eigenvalues are sorted in order of decreasing absolute value.

In your case, executing

- `v[1]` means [`EigenValues`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/EigenValues.html) takes numeric arguments, thus the sorting in the output.
- `v[t]/.t->1` takes the symbolic eigenvalues and then replaces `t` with 1, thus no sorting.

To avoid that you may use `Set (=)` (atleast for this case) for the definition of `v[t]`

```
v[t_] = Eigenvalues[H[t]]
```

Comment: In my code, the formula for val[t] differs from time to time ? Is it correct to use ( = ) instead of ( := )  ?

Comment: It depends on the input. Can you elaborate a bit more?

Comment: I used  SetDelayed because the rhs, Eigenvalues[H[t]], changes with respect to time.

Comment: Usually, function definitions use `SetDelayed`, but in some cases you can use `Set`. For example, `v[t] = Sin[t]` works similar to `v[t]:= Sin[t]`. Check the discussion: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/8829/what-is-the-difference-between-set-and-setdelayed

Comment: Yes, but if you set   v[t] = b* Sin[t] and b changes value at t = t0, then the expression will be evaluated for the initial value of b.