# Functionalize fit

Tags: functions

Simple question, suppose I want to fit data and use

```
Fit[data, {x^4, x^3, x^2, x, 1}, x]
```

I want to convert the output of fit into a function I can later use. 
However, I can't put `fit[x]:=` before the previous code since it just overwrites the value of x in the `Fit`. How do I do this?

Comment: Probably was asked before but can't find it: `fit[x_]:=Evaluate @ Fit[...`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

So, two easy ways to handle this. One involves manipulating the order of evaluation, and the other involves using a fitting function that returns a functional object.

First:

```
f[x_] := Evaluate[Fit[data, {x^4, x^3, x^2, x, 1}, x]];
```

This evaluates the `Fit` before setting `f[x_]:=` to it.

Secondly:

```
f = LinearModelFit[data, {x^4, x^3, x^2, x}, x]
```

`LinearModelFit` returns a model object, which can be called as a function, but has a bunch of other useful properties such as R-squared values and an ANOVA table. These can be examined by calling `f["Properties"]` and the various labels that shows, such as `f["RSquared"]`. Note that `LinearModelFit`, by default, includes a constant term automatically. This can be disabled by setting `IncludeConstantBasis -> False`.

You may also be interested in knowing that `NonlinearModelFit` exists and has similar properties, if you end up having to deal with more complicated models.

---

It has also been pointed out by @HenrikSchumacher and @SjoerdSmit that this is a case where using `Set` instead of `SetDelayed` to define the function has the expected and desired result:

```
f[x_] = Fit[data, {x^4, x^3, x^2, x, 1}, x];
```

This is actually functionally the same as using `Evaluate` in the `SetDelayed` expression. I'd recommend checking [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/8829/what-is-the-difference-between-set-and-setdelayed/8831#8831) for further reading regarding `:=` and `=`.

Comment: I like the second option better, thank you.

Comment: Should be also possible: `f[x_] = Fit[data, {x^4, x^3, x^2, x, 1}, x];`

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher: exactly. This is basically the only time you ever use regular `Set` (`=` instead of `:=`) to define a function.

Comment: I was hesitant to edit in an answer that involved `f[x_] =`, since 4 of the most upvoted posts involving `Set` vs. `SetDelayed` seem to be from "common pitfalls for new users", but I couldn't find any particular reasoning to recommend against it after looking, so I've added it here. Thanks.

Comment: really concise and useful answer; kudos