# Should a new user just default to LinearModelFit (vs Fit)

Tags: fitting

I tried searching but the noise in the responses is high due to 'fit' being both a function and a valid term.

If I'm new to Mathematica should I just default to `LinearModelFit` (v7) and recognise `Fit` as a v1 version that got superceded?

My instinct is 'yes' but wondered if there were valid use cases where Fit would be preferred over LinearModelFit.

Comment: You may want to take a look at https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/182053/functionalize-fit/182055#182055 for an example of some of the usage differences. `LinearModelFit` generates a model object which has some useful properties (e.g. "RSquared"), in addition to the fit itself. In short, I'd only recommend `Fit` if you just want the shortest code for getting the linear fit expression without any other baggage.

Comment: thx, if i'd found that i wouldn't have asked.

Comment: See also [Difference between fitting algorithms](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/80998/27951)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are a few major differences between `Fit` and `LinearModelFit`.

`LinearModelFit` generates a full model object as its output, which maintains a large set of interesting properties (such as `RSquared` or `ANOVATable`). These can be accessed by:

```
lmf = LinearModelFit[{2, 3, 4, 5}, {x}, x];
lmf["Properties"]
lmf["RSquared"]
```

By default, `LinearModelFit` assumes that the zero-intercept may be non-zero. This property is controlled by the `IncludeConstantBasis` option. `LinearModelFit` has several interesting but advanced options available as well, such as the ability to define weights and perform error propagation through the model.

The final fit expression from `LinearModelFit` can be extracted with `Normal`.

`Fit` does not assume a constant basis, and returns the fit expression directly. It does not calculate additional properties, will automatically convert exact numbers to machine precision, and only finds the least-squares fit. `LinearModelFit` and `Fit` can work at arbitrary precision (as unlikely as that may be to be useful), but only `LinearModelFit` allows the specification of `WorkingPrecision` as an option.

The primary advantage of `Fit` would appear to be its simplicity and brevity. If you only need the least-squares fit expression or are doing code-golf, `Fit` should suffice. In most other cases, I would recommend using `LinearModelFit`, if only to be able to access the various quality measures it can calculate on the side.

Note, however, that I wouldn't expect either function to have significant errors -- they ultimately should find the same model, assuming that the constant basis is either included or excluded in both, and that no special options are specified in `LinearModelFit` to adapt the model to a specific use case. It's just a question of if you want/need the additional data of the model object.

Comment: I believe `LinearModelFit` uses `Fit` behind the scenes (not sure).

Comment: @Szabolcs I just spent a few minutes `PrintDefinitions`ing `LinearModelFit` and didn't see any usage of `Fit` specifically.

Comment: What is PrintDefinitions? Can't find it in the documentation.

Comment: @PaulCommentary Import GeneralUtilities with ``Needs["GeneralUtilities`"]`` and then run `?PrintDefinitions` for its documentation. I'm not sure why it isn't in F1 personally, but that should get you started.