# How to evaluate fit at a fixed point

Tags: fitting

How can I evaluate the result of `Fit` applied to the data used in the example code below

```
data = {{0, 1}, {1, 0}, {3, 2}, {5, 4}};

line = Fit[data, {1, x}, x]
```

How do I now evaluate the function line at a particular point where `x = 2.5` let's say.

Comment: The answer to this question is here: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/182053/functionalize-fit

Comment: The best way is not to use `Fit` in the first place.  Use `LinearModelFit` or `NonlinearModelFit` and you'll also have access to estimates of standard errors, confidence bands, goodness-of-fit statistics, etc.

Comment: `line /. x -> 2.5` gives `1.92373`