# Why does sol[r][[1]] become r?

Tags: numerical-integration, evaluation

This is a follow up to [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/190574/8822) question. [This](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/190615/8822) answer is great it gives the correct solution and I can plot it, but I have a problem: when I try to integrate the solution in this way:

```
NIntegrate[(sol[r][[1]]/.{t->t0})r^2,{r,10^7,10^8}]
```

whith $t_0$ fixed, the solution obtained before is somehow lost and I have `sol[r][[1]]=r`. How can I integrate `sol[r][[1]]`?

Maybe I should add that I integrate in a different cell

Comment: I don't think it's reasonable to expect people will follow your links to dig out the value of `sol`. Link's are OK for further context, leave them in, but please [edit] you question to make it as self contained as possible. Ideally a simple *copy&paste* should be enough to reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The argument of `NIntegrate` has to be numeric.

Try

```
sol = ParametricNDSolveValue[{eq, ic}, {\[CapitalSigma] , h, T}, {t,0, t0}, {r}] 
(* without "[t]" *)

f[r_?NumericQ] := sol[r][[1]][t0] r^2 (*integrand*)
NIntegrate [f[r], {r, 10^4, 10^5}]
(*0.0281089*)
```

Answer (score 2):

Answering the question in the title, which seems only tangentially related to the question in the body.

The expression `sol[r][[1]]` is equivalent to `Part[sol[r], 1]`.  It wants the first *part* of `sol[r]`.  If `sol[r]` evaluates to something like `{a, b, c}`, then the first part would be `a`.  If it does not evaluate, then the first part of `sol[r]` is `r`, and that is what is returned.

Comment: It's always a dilemma, whether to answer the question asked or address what you perceive is the OP's true desire. (+1) -- If you wanted to address the other question, you might suggest `Indexed` to replace `Part`.