# How to speed up the production of this plot?

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, numerical-integration, performance-tuning

This is a followup question to [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/190574/8822) question. From [these](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/190615/8822) [two](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/204062/8822) answers I can build the function `sol[r][[1]][t0]` as follows:

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
Md = 10^(-9);
P = 10;
R = 10^4;
α = 10^(-2);
ϵ = 10^(-4);
γ = 10^(-2);
ke = 0.02*(1 + 0.6625);
k0 = 5*10^20;
σ = 5.67*10^-8;
Rg = 8315;
c = 3*10^8;
G = 6.67/10^11;
M = 2.8*10^30;

Ωk[r_] := Sqrt[(G*M)/r^3];
μ = Md/(3*Pi);
κ = (27*ke)/(2*σ) Rg/μ;
ic = {Co[0] == 1, β[0] == 
    0, Σ[
     0] == (μ^(3/5)*Ωk[
         r]^(2/5)) (κ^(-1/5)*α^(-4/5)*Co[0]^(-1/5)),
   h[0] == (κ*α*Σ[0]^2*
       Co[0]/Ωk[r]^5)^(1/6),
   T[0] == (1/2)*(Ωk[r]*h[0])^2*(μ/
       Rg)*(1/(1 + β[0])),
   Kkr[0] == (k0*(Σ[0]*h[0]))/T[0]^(7/2)};

eq = {Σ'[
     t] == -Σ[
       t] + κ^(-1/5) α^(-4/5) μ^(3/
         5) Ωk[r]^(2/5)*Co[t]^(-1/5),
   h'[t] == -h[
       t] + (κ α Σ[t]^2 Ωk[
          r]^(-5) Co[t])^(1/6),
   T'[t] == -T[t] + 
     1/2 μ/Rg (Ωk[r]^2 h[t]^2)/(1 + β[t]),
   Kkr'[t] == -Kkr[t] + k0 Σ[t]/h[t]*T[t]^(-7/2),
   β'[
     t] == -β[t] + μ/
       Rg (4 σ)/(3 c) T[t]^3/Σ[t] h[t],
   Co'[t] == -Co[t] + (1 + β[t])^4*(1 + Kkr[t]/ke)};



t0 = 20; sol = 
 ParametricNDSolveValue[{eq, ic}, {Σ, h, 
   T}, {t, 0, t0}, {r}]
```

Now I need to perform the following integral for a plot:

```
int[r_?NumericQ, t_?NumericQ] := sol[r][[1]][t0] r^3 Cos[2 CapitalOmega]k[r] t]
F1[t_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[int[r, t], {r, 10^6, 10^8}]
Plot[F1[t], {t, 0, 3*10^3}]
```

In a whole night this code has not produced the plot. I tried with memoization for the function `int`:

```
 int[r_?NumericQ, t_?NumericQ] := int[r,t]=sol[r][[1]][t0] r^3 Cos[2 CapitalOmega]k[r] t]
```

but nothing has changed.  I tried with with `ParallelTable`, but Mathematica says it cannot communicate with the kernels (or something like that) and a simple `Table[F1[t],{t,0,1000,100}]` still has not produced an output.

How can I produce the desired plot?

**EDIT** Using memoization on `sol[r][[1]][t0]` (`h[r_?NumericQ]:=h[r]=sol[r][[1]][t0]`) makes things faster, but it still takes about half an hour on my laptop. Is it possible to do better? Moreover there are some numerical issues in the plot:

[image]

**EDIT2** I have solved the numerical issues by using `MinRecursion->5`, but it slows down the computation even more. Any suggestions are welcome.

**EDIT3** Would it be possible to integrate using `NDSolve` like in [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/104553/8822) question? I tried with:

```
ParametricNDSolveValue[F[t]==sol[r][[1]][600]r^3Cos[ CapitalOmegak[r] t],{r,10^6,10^8},{t}]
```

but it does not work.

Comment: You have constants that differ by **dozens of orders of magnitude**, which will make numerical calculations slow and unreliable. Please, work in **natural units**, where all constants are of order 1. Thanks.

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform It's not necessary when options about precision and accuracy are proper enough AFAIK, an example: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/23696/1871 (Compare Goofy and Michael's answers there. )

Comment: @xzczd: That's true to a certain extend, but properly re-scaling the problem will make it possible to stay within the realm of machine precision arithmetic, which is generally faster than arbitrary-precision calculations. It may or may not be the magic bullet for this particular problem, but rescaling is almost always a good idea nonetheless.

Comment: @SjoerdSmit Yeah, `WorkingPrecision` will usually make the code slower, but _Mathematica_ won't switch to arbitrary-precision calculation if we only adjust `PrecisionGoal` and `AccuracyGoal`. (Just check the timing of Goofy and Michael's solutions. )