# Inactive nonlinear ODE system results in NDSolveValue::femcnmd warning

Tags: differential-equations, finite-element-method

I am currently trying to solve a set of 1D steady state ODEs using `NDSolveValue` in the form of `Inactive[Grad]` and `Inactive[Div]`. However, I encountered error:

> NDSolveValue::femcnmd: The PDE coefficient 0. does not evaluate to a
> numeric matrix of dimensions {1,1} at the coordinate {0.000025}; it
> evaluated to 0. instead.

Here is the essential code:

Creating mesh,

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
k = 1;
m = 5;
d[x_] = 0.5/1000*(1 - Tanh[m*(x + 10)]) + 
   0.5/1000*(1 - Tanh[-m*(x - 2)]) + 0.00005/k;(*With dip*)
xlist = {0};
xend = xlist[[Length[xlist]]];
coord = {{1}};
i = 1;
While[xend < 4,
 i = i + 1;
 coord = Join[coord, {{i}}];
 xend = xend + d[xend];
 If[xend > 4, xend = 4;, xend = xend;];
 xlist = Insert[xlist, xend, (Length[xlist] + 1)];
 ]
(*ReplacePart[xlist,Length[xlist]->4]*)
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]
xmesh = ToElementMesh[Map[{#} &, xlist]];
```

Defining ODEs and Boundary conditions to solve using NDSolveValue,

```
testEquations = {-50.5` x^2 a[x] phi[x] (1 - Tanh[20 (-1 + x)]) + 
     Inactive[
       Div][(x^2 a[
         x] Inactive[
          Grad][(-1 + Log[a[x]] + Tanh[20 (-1 + x)]), {x}]), {x}] == 
    NeumannValue[0, x == 0], 
   50.` x^2 a[x] phi[x] (1 - Tanh[20 (-1 + x)]) + 
     Inactive[
       Div][(x^2 b[
         x] Inactive[
          Grad][(-1 + Log[b[x]] + Tanh[20 (-1 + x)]), {x}]), {x}] == 
    NeumannValue[0, x == 0], 
   0.05` x^2 a[x] phi[x] (1 - Tanh[20 (-1 + x)]) + 
     0.001` Inactive[
        Div][(x^2 (1 - phi[x]) Inactive[Grad][
          Log[10.` (1 - phi[x])], {x}]), {x}] == 
    NeumannValue[0, x == 0], a[4] == 1, b[4] == 0, phi[4] == 1.`};
testSolution = 
  NDSolveValue[testEquations , {a, b, phi}, Element[x, xmesh]];
```

Apart from that, is it possible to perform divergence on a 1D vector in spherical coordinate for my ODEs (to become equivalent to [image])? Currently, I have to manually converting to this using cartesian form by performing multiplication of `r^2` into the vector.

Comment: Can we avoid 1/0 error when `b[4]==0` and in equations there is `1/b[x]` ?

Comment: @AlexTrounev Do you mean that when we expand the divergence term in second ODE?

Comment: Yes it is, second equation looks like `50 x^2 a[x] phi[x] (1 - Tanh[20 (-1 + x)]) + 
  2 x b[x] (20 Sech[20 (-1 + x)]^2 + Derivative[1][b][x]/b[x]) + 
  x^2 Derivative[1][b][
    x] (20 Sech[20 (-1 + x)]^2 + Derivative[1][b][x]/b[x]) + 
  x^2 b[x] (-800 Sech[20 (-1 + x)]^2 Tanh[20 (-1 + x)] - 
     Derivative[1][b][x]^2/b[x]^2 + (b^\[Prime]\[Prime])[x]/b[x]) == 0` . There are several terms with `1/b[x], 1/b[x]^2` while `b[4]==0`.

Comment: This system can be solved with collocation method - see my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"I want to solve a differential equation system. I have a quick search, it seems that everybody is talking about a powerful method called FEM, so I decide to use it, too." ← If this is the reason you keep trying solving your nonlinear ODE system with `FiniteElement` method, please remember, there is no silver bullet. Though it's hot these days, finite element method has its own drawbacks, and you've encountered the most troublesome one (in my view).

The warning can be reproduced with the following sample (you should have put more effort in simplifying your code sample BTW):

```
eqsample = 1. Inactive[Div][Inactive[Grad][1. phi[x] + 1, {x}], {x}] == 0;
NDSolveValue[{eqsample, phi[0] == 0, phi[4] == 1}, phi, x ∈ xmesh]
```

> NDSolveValue::femcnmd: The PDE coefficient 0.` does not evaluate to a
> numeric matrix of dimensions {1,1} at the coordinate {0.000025}; it
> evaluated to 0.` instead.

Definition of `xmesh` is the same as yours. I use it to reproduce exactly the same warning as mentioned in the question. If you use `{x, 0, 4}` instead, the warning will be

> NDSolveValue::femcnmd: The PDE coefficient 0.` does not evaluate to a
> numeric matrix of dimensions {1,1} at the coordinate {**2.**}; it
> evaluated to 0.` instead.

`NDSolve` shouldn't have any difficulty in handling `eqsample`, it's just a simple `phi''[x] == 0`:

```
eqsample // Activate
(* 1. phi''[x] == 0 *)
```

Further check proves something is wrong in parsing stage:

```
NDSolve`ProcessEquations[{eqsample, phi[0] == 0, phi[4] == 1}, phi, {x, 0, 4}]
```

> NDSolveValue::femcnmd ……

Why does this happen? It's because that, in order to solve differential equation, `NDSolve` always need to transform the equation to certain *standard form*. Different standard forms are required by different methods. (For example, standard forms of initial value problem of ODE is discussed in [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/158519/1871). ) **`FiniteElement` method is bounded in the most complicated and restricted standard form (which is called formal form or inactive form in document) of `NDSolve`**. This makes the pre-processing of `FiniteElement` method rather hard and error-prone. The topic is non-trivial so I'd like not to talk too much about it in this post, please read through [Formal Partial Differential Equations](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/tutorial/FiniteElementBestPractice.html#1585211872)
 section in the document for more info. In short:

1. Simply re-write the equation with `Inactive[Grad]` and `Inactive[Div]` is often insufficient.
2. Personally I suggest one always check if the equation is parsed properly with [`` NDSolve`FEM`GetInactivePDE ``](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/225841/1871).

"OK, then how to help `FiniteElement` parsing the equation system? " I don't know, and I don't bother to. The biggest advantage of `FiniteElement` (in my view) is its capability for solving PDE(s) on irregular domain, but you're just dealing with an ODE system! Why not turning to the old-good finite difference method (FDM)?

I'll use [`pdetoae`](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/127997/1871) for the task. Definition of `testEquations` is the same as yours.

```
{eq, bc} = {testEquations[[;; -4]], {testEquations[[-3 ;;]], 
            phi'[0] == 0, a'[0] == 0, b'[0] == 0}} /. NeumannValue[__] :> 0 // Activate;

domain = {0, 4};
points = 500;
grid = Array[#1 &, points, domain];
difforder = 4;    
(* Definition of pdetoae isn't included in this post,
   please find it in the link above. *)
ptoafunc = pdetoae[{a, b, phi}[x], grid, difforder];
ae = (#1[[2 ;; -2]] &) /@ ptoafunc[eq];
aebc = ptoafunc[bc];
icguess[var_][x_] := 1;
solrule = FindRoot[
   Flatten[{ae, aebc}], (Flatten[#1, 1] &)[
    Table[{var[x], icguess[var][x]}, {var, {a, b, phi}}, {x, grid}]], 
            Jacobian -> "FiniteDifference"]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {0.990207, Null} *)
{afunc, bfunc, phifunc} = 
  ListInterpolation[#, grid] & /@ Partition[solrule[[All, -1]], points];
ListLinePlot[{afunc, bfunc, phifunc}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Comment: This is a nice solution (+1). Why it is not correlated with wavelets method?

Comment: @AlexTrounev I'm not knowledgable enough to explain this, but the convergency of the discretized system doesn't seem to be fast, for example, if I decrease the difference order to `difforder = 2;`, the numeric error is still obvious even for `points = 800;`. Might be related to the sudden change around `x == 1`?

Comment: Ok! Finally I got your solution with 512 collocation points - see update to my answer. But my code is terribly slow compare to yours.

Comment: @Alex Adding `Jacobian -> "FiniteDifference"` to `FindRoot` speeds up your code. With this option, it takes about 90 seconds on my laptop. Without it, the calculation doesn't finish for several minutes. (We also need to add `Exclusions -> None` to `Plot` in this case. )

Comment: Thank you very much, this option really works.

Answer (score 4):

This problem can be solved with using the Euler wavelets collocation method described [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/262458/unbounded-solution-at-boundaries-with-few-combination-of-values-in-this-bvp-solu/262563#262563), [here](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/2457908), and [hear](https://www.mdpi.com/2075-1680/10/3/165). First we rationalize coefficients and map solution on the unit interval, then we have

```
Clear["Global`*"]

testEquations = {-505/10 L0^2 x^2 a[x] phi[
       x] (1 - Tanh[20 (-1 + L0 x)]) + 
     D[(x^2 a[
         x] D[(-1 + Log[a[x]] + Tanh[20 (-1 + L0 x)]), {x}]), {x}] == 
    0, 50 L0^2 x^2 a[x] phi[x] (1 - Tanh[20 (-1 + L0 x)]) + 
     D[x^2 b[x] D[(-1 + Log[b[x]] + 
          Tanh[20 (-1 + L0 x)]), {x}], {x}] == 0, 
   5/100  L0^2 x^2 a[x] phi[x] (1 - Tanh[20 (-1 + L0 x)]) + 
     1/1000 D[(x^2 (1 - phi[x]) D[Log[10 (1 - phi[x])], {x}]), {x}] ==
     0};
```

Let transform system to the collocation method

```
 testEquations /. {a'[x] -> a1[x], a''[x] -> a2[x], 
  b'[x] -> b1[x], b''[x] -> b2[x], phi'[x] -> phi1[x], 
  phi''[x] -> phi2[x]}

Out[]= {2 x a[x] (a1[x]/a[x] + 20 L0 Sech[20 (-1 + L0 x)]^2) + 
   x^2 a1[x] (a1[x]/a[x] + 20 L0 Sech[20 (-1 + L0 x)]^2) - 
   101/2 L0^2 x^2 a[x] phi[x] (1 - Tanh[20 (-1 + L0 x)]) + 
   x^2 a[x] (-(a1[x]^2/a[x]^2) + a2[x]/a[x] - 
      800 L0^2 Sech[20 (-1 + L0 x)]^2 Tanh[20 (-1 + L0 x)]) == 0, 
 2 x b[x] (b1[x]/b[x] + 20 L0 Sech[20 (-1 + L0 x)]^2) + 
   x^2 b1[x] (b1[x]/b[x] + 20 L0 Sech[20 (-1 + L0 x)]^2) + 
   50 L0^2 x^2 a[x] phi[x] (1 - Tanh[20 (-1 + L0 x)]) + 
   x^2 b[x] (-(b1[x]^2/b[x]^2) + b2[x]/b[x] - 
      800 L0^2 Sech[20 (-1 + L0 x)]^2 Tanh[20 (-1 + L0 x)]) == 
  0, (-2 x phi1[x] - x^2 phi2[x])/1000 + 
   1/20 L0^2 x^2 a[x] phi[x] (1 - Tanh[20 (-1 + L0 x)]) == 0}
```

This system we transform to the algebraic system as follows

```
UE[m_, t_] := EulerE[m, t]
psi[k_, n_, m_, t_] := 
 Piecewise[{{2^(k/2) Sqrt[2/Pi] UE[m, 2^k t - 2 n + 1], (n - 1)/
      2^(k - 1) <= t < n/2^(k - 1)}, {0, True}}]
PsiE[k_, M_, t_] := 
 Flatten[Table[psi[k, n, m, t], {n, 1, 2^(k - 1)}, {m, 0, M - 1}]]
k0 = 7; M0 = 8; With[{k = k0, M = M0}, 
 nn = Length[Flatten[Table[1, {n, 1, 2^(k - 1)}, {m, 0, M - 1}]]]];
dx = 1/(nn);  xl = Table[ l*dx, {l, 0, nn}];  
 xcol = Table[(xl[[l - 1]] + xl[[l]])/2, {l, 2, nn + 1}]; Psijk = 
 With[{k = k0, M = M0}, PsiE[k, M, t1]]; Int1 = 
 With[{k = k0, M = M0}, Integrate[PsiE[k, M, t1], t1]];
Int2 = Integrate[Int1, t1]; Psi[y_] := Psijk /. t1 -> y; 
int1[y_] := Int1 /. t1 -> y; int2[y_] := Int2 /. t1 -> y;


var1 = Array[v1, {nn}]; var2 = Array[v2, {nn}]; var3 = 
 Array[v3, {nn}]; con = Array[c, {6}];
L0 = 4; a2[x_] = var1 . Psi[x]; a1[x_] = var1 . int1[x] + c[1]; 
a[x_] = var1 . int2[x] + c[1] x + c[2];
b2[x_] = var2 . Psi[x]; b1[x_] = var2 . int1[x] + c[3]; 
b[x_] = var2 . int2[x] + c[3] x + c[4];
phi2[x_] = var3 . Psi[x]; phi1[x_] = var3 . int1[x] + c[5]; 
phi[x_] = var3 . int2[x] + c[5] x + c[6]; var = 
 Join[var1, var2, var3, con];


eq = Flatten[
   Table[{2 x a[x] (a1[x]/a[x] + 20 L0 Sech[20 (-1 + L0 x)]^2) + 
       x^2 a1[x] (a1[x]/a[x] + 20 L0 Sech[20 (-1 + L0 x)]^2) - 
       101/2 L0^2 x^2 a[x] phi[x] (1 - Tanh[20 (-1 + L0 x)]) + 
       x^2 a[x] (-(a1[x]^2/a[x]^2) + a2[x]/a[x] - 
          800 L0^2 Sech[20 (-1 + L0 x)]^2 Tanh[20 (-1 + L0 x)]) == 0, 
     2 x b[x] (b1[x]/b[x] + 20 L0 Sech[20 (-1 + L0 x)]^2) + 
       x^2 b1[x] (b1[x]/b[x] + 20 L0 Sech[20 (-1 + L0 x)]^2) + 
       50 L0^2 x^2 a[x] phi[x] (1 - Tanh[20 (-1 + L0 x)]) + 
       x^2 b[x] (-(b1[x]^2/b[x]^2) + b2[x]/b[x] - 
          800 L0^2 Sech[20 (-1 + L0 x)]^2 Tanh[20 (-1 + L0 x)]) == 
      0, (-2 x phi1[x] - x^2 phi2[x])/1000 + 
       1/20 L0^2 x^2 a[x] phi[x] (1 - Tanh[20 (-1 + L0 x)]) == 0}, {x,
      xcol}]];
```

Finally we add boundary conditions and solve with `FindRoot`

```
bc = {a[x] == 1, b[x] == 0, phi[x] == 1} /. 
  x -> 1; bc1 = {a1[x] == 0, b1[x] == 0, phi1[x] == 0} /. x -> 0;

eqs = Join[eq, bc, bc1];

sol = FindRoot[eqs, Table[{var[[i]], 1/10}, {i, Length[var]}],Jacobian -> "FiniteDifference"];
```

Visualization

```
Plot[Evaluate[{a[x/L0] /. sol, b[x/L0] /. sol, phi[x/L0] /. sol}], {x,
   0, L0}, PlotLegends -> {"a", "b", "phi"}, Exclusions -> None]
```

[image: Figure 1]

We also can solve this problem with linear FEM, using iterative false transient algorithm  discussed [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/190574/how-can-i-solve-iteratively-for-sigmar-tr-and-hr/190615#190615), [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/204518/finite-element-for-coupled-1d-and-3d-equations/204559#204559), and [here](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1433064). We use transformed system of equations with adding iteration parameter `dt=1/5` and linearized as follows

```
Clear["Global`*"]

Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]
xmesh = ToElementMesh[ImplicitRegion[0 <= x <= 1, {x}], 
  MaxCellMeasure -> 2 10^-3]
eqn = {-(a[x] - A[i - 1][x])/dt - 
    808  a[x] P[i - 1][x] (1 - Tanh[20 (-1 + 4 x)]) + 
    2/x  (80 Sech[20 (-1 + 4 x)]^2 a[x] + 
       Derivative[1][a][x]) +  (80 Sech[20 (-1 + 4 x)]^2 Derivative[
        1][a][x] + 
      A1[i - 1][x] a'[x]/A[i - 1][x]) +  (-12800 Sech[
        20 (-1 + 4 x)]^2 Tanh[20 (-1 + 4 x)] a[x] - 
      A1[i - 1][x] a'[x]/A[i - 1][x] + (a^\[Prime]\[Prime])[x]) == 
   NeumannValue[0, x == 0], -(b[x] - B[i - 1][x])/dt + 
    800  P[i - 1][x] a[x] (1 - Tanh[20 (-1 + 4 x)]) + 
    2/x  (80 Sech[20 (-1 + 4 x)]^2 b[x] + 
       Derivative[1][b][x]) + (80 Sech[20 (-1 + 4 x)]^2 Derivative[1][
        b][x] + B1[i - 1][x] b'[x]/B[i - 1][x]) + (-12800 Sech[
        20 (-1 + 4 x)]^2 Tanh[20 (-1 + 4 x)] b[x] - 
      B1[i - 1][x] b'[x]/B[i - 1][x] + (b^\[Prime]\[Prime])[x]) == 
   NeumannValue[0, x == 0], (phi[x] - P[i - 1][x])/dt + 
    4/5  P[i - 1][x] a[
      x] (1 - Tanh[20 (-1 + 4 x)]) + (-2/x  Derivative[1][phi][x] - (
      phi^\[Prime]\[Prime])[x])/1000 == NeumannValue[0, x == 0]}; bc =
  DirichletCondition[{a[x] == 1, b[x] == 0, phi[x] == 1}, x == 1];
```

Initial guess is very important in this case, but we use the simple one

```
A[0][x_] := 1; B[0][x_] = 1/100; P[0][x_] = 1; A1[0][x_] := 0; 
B1[0][x_] = 0; P1[0][x_] := 0;

L0 = 4; dt = 
 1/5; nn = 231; Do[{A[i], B[i], P[i], A1[i], B1[i], P1[i]} = 
   NDSolveValue[{eqn, bc}, {a, b, phi, a', b', phi'}, 
    Element[{x}, xmesh]]; , {i, 1, nn}]
```

Visualization

```
Table[Plot[Evaluate[{A[i][x/L0], B[i][x/L0], P[i][x/L0]}], {x, 0, L0},
   PlotLegends -> {"a", "b", "phi"}, PlotRange -> All, 
  PlotLabel -> i], {i, 228, 231}]
```

Also FEM solution looks similar to above computed with wavelets and  computed with `pdetoae` at xzczd post, the algorithm not stable and solution diverges at `nn>231`.

[image: Figure 2]

Comment: There seem to be simple mistakes in mapping, for example, `D[(x^2 a[x] D[…` should be `D[((L0 x)^2 a[x] D[…`. I suggest using `DSolveChangeVariables` or [`DChange`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/80241/1871) to avoid possible mistakes.

Comment: Actually there is no mistake in mapping, since we can test my `testEquations` with `bc, bc1` with your code and got absolutely same result as yours. But solution strictly depends on the number of collocation points. May be this is a problem?

Comment: Oh you're right, I forgot about the `L0` generated by `D`… With `M0 = 9` our results (almost) matches :) .

Comment: Yes, but in my example there is 98 points and I have tested it with 112 and 128 points as well. May be there are several branches in numerical solution?

Comment: If the system owns multiple solutions, according to my (limited) experience, the initial guess should play an important role, but this problem doesn't seem to be the case…

Comment: @xzczd Finally I got right solution with 512 collocation points. Therefore the number of points is the main factor since function `Tanh[20 (-1 + L0 x)]` needs to be resolved.