# How can I evaluate a symbolic matrix

Tags: matrix

For example if I have:

```
Matriz = {{a, b}, {c, d}}
Matriz2[a_, b_, c_, d_] := Matriz;
```

when I run Matrix2 [1,2,3,4], the matrix is not evaluated.  I would not like to use /.{a->..} because the parameter a and b are function of other variables.

Thanks

Comment: try `Matrix2[a_, b_, c_, d_] := Evaluate@Matriz`?

Comment: Mandatory reading: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/8829/what-is-the-difference-between-set-and-setdelayed

Comment: when i put the followings, the mathematica dont change the a value of matriz. f[a_] := NIntegrate[x, {x, 1, a}];
g[a_] := NIntegrate[Sin[x], {x, 1, a}];
matriz = {{a + ff, a - gg}};
Matriz22[a_] := Hold[Evaluate@(matriz /. {ff -> f[a], gg -> g[a]})]
ReleaseHold[Matriz22[2]]