# Defining a function and order of operations

Tags: list-manipulation, functions, map

I feel I have a profound misunderstanding of how Mathematica works. Here's an example that confuses me: Say that for a matrix $A$ I want to extract the first $\mathrm{Tr}(A)$ normalized eigenvectors (the trace is guaranteed to be an integer). I would write a function

```
f[A_]= Normalize /@ Part[Part[Eigensystem[A], 2] , Range[Tr[A]]];
v=f[A]
```

Nevertheless this doesn't work, it just outputs

```
Normalize[{...}]
```

and $...$ are the unnormalized eigenvectors. Meanwhile, if  write

```
f[A_]= Part[Part[Eigensystem[A], 2] , Range[Tr[A]]];
v=Normalize /@ f[A]
```

it works perfectly. What is going on here?

Comment: Can you provide an example with a suitable matrix A?

Comment: I will. By the way, I just solved my problem by replacing f[A_]= ... with f[A_]:= ..., but I don't understand what's the difference between these two..

Comment: @user2723984 See [(8829)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/8829/121) and links therein.