# Optimization for plotting

Tags: plotting, performance-tuning

I would like to know if there is any way to improve the speed of the following program:

```
f := 1 - (2 M)/r; M = 1;

Va := f ((l (l + 1))/r^2 + ((1 - S^2) \!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(r\)]f\))/r);(*Axial potential*)

rmin := r /. Last[FindMaximum[{V, r > M}, r]]

V1 := f \!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(r\)]V\);
V2 := f \!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(r\)]V1\);
V3 := f \!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(r\)]V2\);
V4 := f \!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(r\)]V3\);
V5 := f \!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(r\)]V4\);
V6 := f \!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(r\)]V5\);

\[CapitalGamma] := 
  1/Sqrt[-2 V2] (1/8 (V4/V2) (1/4 + (n + 1/2)^2) - 
     1/288 (V3/V2)^2 (7 + 60 (n + 1/2)^2));
\[CapitalOmega] := 
  1/(-2 V2) (5/6912 (V3 /V2)^4 (77 + 188 (n + 1/2)^2) - 
     1/384 (((V3)^2  V4)/(V2)^3) (51 + 100 (n + 1/2)^2) + 
     1/2304 (V4/V2)^2 (67 + 68 (n + 1/2)^2) + 
     1/288 ((V3 V5)/(V2)^2) (19 + 28 (n + 1/2)^2) - 
     1/288 (V6/V2) (5 + 4 (n + 1/2)^2));

\[Omega] := Sqrt[
  V + \[CapitalGamma] Sqrt[(-2 V2)] - 
   I (n + 1/2) (1 + \[CapitalOmega]) Sqrt[(-2 V2)]];

(**********Plots**********)
V := Va;
S = 0;
Print[Style["Scalar perturbation", {Bold, Larger}], " Spin = ", S]

pp = 100;

l = 2; n = 0;
P1 = Plot[{Re[\[Omega]] /. r -> rmin, -Im[\[Omega]] /. 
      r -> rmin }, {M, 10^-3, 30}, AxesLabel -> {"M", "\[Omega]"}, 
    PlotStyle -> {{Line, Blue}, {Dashed, Blue}}, 
    PlotLegends -> Placed[{"\[ScriptL]=2"}, {0.7, 0.8}], 
    PlotRange -> {{0, 30}, {0, Automatic}}, MaxRecursion -> Infinity, 
    PlotPoints -> pp]; // AbsoluteTiming
l = 3; n = 0;
P2 = Plot[{Re[\[Omega]] /. r -> rmin, -Im[\[Omega]] /. 
      r -> rmin }, {M, 10^-3, 30}, AxesLabel -> {"M", "\[Omega]"}, 
    PlotStyle -> {{Line, Red}, {Dashed, Red}}, 
    PlotLegends -> Placed[{"\[ScriptL]=3"}, {0.7, 0.8}], 
    PlotRange -> {{0, 30}, {0, Automatic}}, MaxRecursion -> Infinity, 
    PlotPoints -> pp]; // AbsoluteTiming
l = 4; n = 0;
P3 = Plot[{Re[\[Omega]] /. r -> rmin, -Im[\[Omega]] /. 
      r -> rmin }, {M, 10^-3, 30}, AxesLabel -> {"M", "\[Omega]"}, 
    PlotStyle -> {{Line, Black}, {Dashed, Black}}, 
    PlotLegends -> Placed[{"\[ScriptL]=4"}, {0.7, 0.8}], 
    PlotRange -> {{0, 30}, {0, Automatic}}, MaxRecursion -> Infinity, 
    PlotPoints -> pp]; // AbsoluteTiming

Show[P1, P2, P3, Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {"Mass", "Frequency"}, 
 ImageSize -> Medium]
```

I have to make several analysis for even more complicated Vs, and several different plots. They are taking longer and longer and I have no idea how make this faster. Right now it is taking several minutes to run it.

Comment: You use SetDelayed (:=) in loads of places you don't need it which is a drag on performance. Just use Set (=). Also don't use \[PartialD] - just write `D[V, r]` for instance - as it becomes messy. After changing MaxRecursion to 15 (the max allowed) and making these other edits it takes 0.924229 seconds on my machine though the plot is just flat lines.

Comment: Removing `MaxRecurson` and `PlotPoints` makes no difference to me visually, and of course it's much, much faster. (I don't see flat lines like flinty. I see curves.)

Comment: Also your `rmin := r /. Last[FindMaximum[{V, r > M}, r]]` comes before the definition of `V`, you should move `V` up.

Comment: @C.E. I added both ````MaxRecursion```` and ````PlotPoints```` hoping that it would be more precise.

Comment: @flinty What is the difference between setting the definition before or after V?

Comment: @EdisonSantos Because when I copy and paste your code and evaluate the notebook top down from a single cell , V is undefined (fresh kernel) and FindMaximum fails. It's best to stick to defining things in order so we don't have to guess evaluation order.

Answer (score 3):

It is quite tedious to modify your code so I will stick to some general hints:

- Your functions are all of relatively simple form it is best to just use their analytical form instead of `SetDelay`, aka `:=`, everything. So write

  `Va[r_] = ... (*yes, no colon here*)`

  instead of:

  `Va := ...`

  The same for all the other definitions.
  [Check this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/8831/49157) why this matters in terms of performance.
- Then write `f'[r]` instead of your partial derivatives in the new function definitions because the other syntax does not work any more now (check this but I think they should all be reasonable algebraically compact)
- Try a `Simplify` for your expressions (might be unnecessary or useless but sometimes gives a speed up afterwards)
- Check if certain functions get evaluated multiple times at the same argument. In this case, try [memoization](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2639/what-does-the-construct-fx-fx-mean/2676#2676)

Comment: Can you elaborate on why you would not use `SetDelayed` in your first general hint? I think it would bring more clarity to this answer!