# Defining a function as a truncated taylors series

Tags: series-expansion

I am trying to numerically find the error of a truncated series. To do so I want to first define a function that is the truncated sum, I cannot seem to do that. All I am tried is not working.

```
f[x_]:=Normal[Series[ArcTan[x], {x, 0, 100}]]
```

Does not work as f[1] evaluates $x$ inside $\arctan$.
I also tried

```
Normal[Series[ArcTan[x], {x, 0, 100}]]
f[x_]:=%
```

But that did not work. When I copy and paste the result of

```
Normal[Series[ArcTan[x], {x, 0, 100}]]
```

It works fine. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you use ".="  the RHS is evaluated later, but you want immediate evaluation with "=":  f[x_] = Normal[Series[ArcTan[x], {x, 0, 100}]]

Comment: @DanielHuber wow that worked! I thought the difference is "=" also outputs f[x] while ":=" defines f without outputting f. There more you know! Thank you very much.

Comment: Or use `Evaluate`: `f[x_] := Evaluate[Normal[...]]`. Note that `x` gets evaluated this way as well as @Daniel's way.  If `x` has a value the definition won't work.  In that case, try `Block[{x}, f[x] = Normal[..]]`

Comment: Related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/8829/what-is-the-difference-between-set-and-setdelayed

Comment: @2132123 in any case, if you don’t want the output, you would just use a semi-colon delimiter to suppress the output :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
f[x_] := Normal[Series[ArcTan[y], {y, 0, 20}]] /. y -> x;
```

Let us check:

```
f[0.1] // N
ArcTan[0.1]

(* 0.0996687

0.0996687   *)

f[1] // N
ArcTan[1.]

(*  0.76046

0.785398   *)
```

The smaller is x the better is the coincidence.

Have fun!

Comment: Could you explain what '''/. y -> x''' ? I think my problem is that I am trying to define a function that has inputs $x,n$ where it outputs evaluation of the truncated sum (n terms) at the point $x$. Using your code works ''' f[x_, k_] := Normal[Series[ArcTan[y], {y, 0, k}]] /. y -> x;'''. Is the issue normally that mathematica cannot expand arctan to $k$ terms without knowing what $k$ is?

Comment: The conflict here is in the part `{x, 0, 100}` of your code. It is since in the left-hand part stays `f [x_]` which means "the function f of any x". In this case Mma does not understand the iteration constructs when "any x" takes part in it. However, if I replace x by y, the operation `Normal[Series[ArcTan[y], {y, 0, 100}]]` will return a polynomial of y. And this is already a simple function, no iterators. Then one replaces y by x. This is done by `.../.y->x`. Have a look at Menu/Help/WolframDocumentation/ReplaceAll.

Answer (score 1):

It is recommend that define Taylor Series by hand since we can also treat **multivariable** Taylor series  at the same time.

```
taylorMulti[f_, x_, x0_, n_] := 
  Sum[1/i! Dot[
     D[f, {{Sequence @@ x}, i}] /. 
      Thread[{Sequence @@ x} -> {Sequence @@ x0}], 
     Sequence @@ 
      ConstantArray[{Sequence @@ x} - {Sequence @@ x0}, i]], {i, 0, 
    n}];
```

```
taylorMulti[Exp[t], t, 0, 5]
taylorMulti[Exp[t], {t}, {0}, 5]
taylorMulti[Exp[t - s], {t, s}, {0, 0}, 3] // Expand
```

> `1 + t + t^2/2 + t^3/6 + t^4/24 + t^5/120`

> `1 - s + s^2/2 - s^3/6 + t - s t + (s^2 t)/2 + t^2/2 - (s t^2)/2 + t^3/ 6`