# Assuming r0 ≈ r1 && r0 ≈ 0 && r1 ≈ 0, to discourage division by near-zero

Tags: assumptions

I’m using Mathematica for some conceptually simple algebra, that will ultimately land in Excel or a compiled language.

```
$Assumptions = Element[{r0,r1,t0,t1,disc0}, Reals] && (t1>t0) && (disc0>0)
(* Also, typically, r0 ≈ r1 && r0 ≈ 0 && r1 ≈ 0 *)

r[t_] = ((t1-t)r0+(t-t0)r1) / (t1-t0)   (* Linear interpolation *)

disc[t_] = disc0 Exp[-Integrate[r[tt], {tt, 0, t}]]

ans = Integrate[disc[t], {t,t0,t1}]

ans // FullSimplify
```

It works, in that it produces an answer. But the answer has multiple divisions by `(r0 - r1)`, or, worse, by its `Sqrt`, As said in the first comment in the code, r0 ≈ r1 && r0 ≈ 0 && r1 ≈ 0. Hence dividing by `(r0 - r1)` is numerically unwise. Please, **is there a means of instructing Mathematica of the approximate equalities, so as to discourage division by things near zero?**

Perhaps relevant: $Version = “9.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (January 24, 2013)”.

Thank you.

Comment: Function definitions should use `:=` rather than `=`.

Comment: Not true, @A.G. and this poor advice leads to many problems for beginners. Both immediate and delayed assignments have important roles to play ([tutorial](https://www.wolfram.com/language/elementary-introduction/2nd-ed/39-immediate-and-delayed-values.html)), and here is a typical example where an immediate assignment makes more sense than a delayed one because we want the `Integrate` command to be executed at definition-time (i.e., only once), not at function-call time (i.e., at every call).

Comment: @Roman I only knew about https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/FunctionsAndPrograms.html ; do you have a reference for using `=` in defining functions?

Comment: [Here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/TransformationRulesAndDefinitions.html#29979) and [here](https://www.wolfram.com/language/elementary-introduction/2nd-ed/39-immediate-and-delayed-values.html) and [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/8829/26598) and links therein. Keep in mind that Mathematica has no concept of "function", only assignments and pattern-matching; there is no category distinction between `a=5` and `a[x_]=5`.

Answer (score 1):

One way around the issue would be to separate three cases: `r0==r1`, `r0<r1` and `r0>r1`:

```
$Assumptions = 
  Element[{r0, r1, t0, t1, disc0}, Reals] && (t1 > t0) && (disc0 > 0);
r[t_] := (r0*(t1-t) + r1*(t-t0))/(t1-t0);  (*Linear interpolation*)
disc[t_] := disc0 Exp[-Integrate[r[tt], {tt, 0, t}]];
ans[t_] := FullSimplify[Integrate[disc[t], {t, t0, t1}]];

Assuming[r0 == r1, ans[t]]
Assuming[r0  < r1, ans[t]]
Assuming[r0  > r1, ans[t]]
```

[image: Output]

Comment: Thank you. However, `(Erf[…/Sqrt[r0−r1]] − Erf[…/Sqrt[r0−r1]]) … / Sqrt[r0−r1] ` is still a numerical disaster.

Answer (score 0):

A series expansion could help. You say that $r_1\approx r_0$, so let's set $r_1=r_0\cdot\rho$ with $\rho=\frac{r_1}{r_0}$ capturing the relationship between $r_0$ and $r_1$.

Now we can series-expand for small $r_0$ because we've tied the magnitudes of $r_1\approx r_0$ together through $\rho$:

```
Series[ans /. r1 -> r0*ρ, {r0, 0, 1}] // FullSimplify
(*    disc0 * (t1-t0) +
      disc0/6 * (2*t0*t1*(ρ-1) - t1^2*(ρ+2) + t0^2*(2ρ+1)) * r0 +
      O[r0]^(3/2)                                                    *)
```

(you can use a higher-oder expansion if you like).

This formula should be stable for small $r_0$. We can back-substitute $r_1$ into it:

```
ans0 = Normal[%] /. ρ -> r1/r0 // FullSimplify
(*    disc0/6*(t0*(r0*t0+2*r1*t0-6) + 2*(3-r0*t0+r1*t0)*t1 - (2*r0+r1)*t1^2)    *)
```

Let's try out this approximation `ans0`:

```
{ans, ans0} /. {disc0 -> 1, t0 -> 0.3, t1 -> 0.8, r0 -> 0.01, r1 -> 0.0101}
(*    {0.497258 + 0. I, 0.49725}    *)
```

A higher-order series-expansion may give a more accurate approximation, if needed.

Comment: Ooh, that is a clean way to capture the relationship. Thank you. I’ll explore this, then perhaps mark as answer. But because they are close to zero, I might expand about the difference rather than about the ratio.