# Plotting a sequence of functions with cases

Tags: plotting, function-construction

How can I plot functions like this
$$f_{2^n+j}(x)=\begin{cases}0, x\in [\frac{j}{2^n},\frac{j+1}{2^n}]\\1, x\in x<\frac{j}{2^n} \text{ or } x>\frac{j+1}{2^n}\end{cases}$$?

I tried something like this:

```
f[j_, n_, x_] = Piecewise[
   {
     {0, j/2^n <= x && x <= (j + 1)/2^n}, 
     {1, x < j/2^n || x > (j + 1)/2^n}
    }
]
```

But it did not help. It is my first time I use this software.

Comment: see [tutorial: Defining Functions](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/FunctionsAndPrograms.html)

Comment: The above is just the definition of the function. It does nothing if you do not call it. A function has to be called to do its work. Did you actually call it? Can you show how? btw, better to use `:=` for function definition. This works `Plot[f[1, 2, x], {x, 0, 1}]` for example.

Comment: see also: [Immediate and delayed definitions](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/TransformationRulesAndDefinitions.html#29979)

Comment: .. and [What is the difference between Set and SetDelayed?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/8829/125)

Comment: @Nasser : Yes. Thanks! It works if it do as you write. My attempt was "Plot[f[j,n,x], {j, 0, 10}, {n, 0, 10}, {x, 0, 10}]". What can I do to have a sequences of $j$ and $n$ in Plot function without specifying paticular numbers (like 1 and 2 in your code)?

Comment: @kglr : Thank you. But there are so much information. I will read it. But now I need express help )

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What can I do to have a sequences of j and n in Plot function without
> specifying paticular numbers

If I understand you right, you can first generate the `j,n` data first

```
Clear["Global`*"]
data = Flatten[Table[{j, n}, {j, 3}, {n, 3}], 1]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Now generate the functions for each `j,n` above

```
f[j_, n_, x_] := 
 Piecewise[{{0, j/2^n <= x && x <= (j + 1)/2^n}, {1, 
    x < j/2^n || x > (j + 1)/2^n}}]

p = f[Sequence @@ #, x] & /@ data
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Now make the plot for each

```
    Grid[Partition[Plot[#, {x, 0, 10}] & /@ p, 3], Frame -> All, 
 Spacings -> {3, 3}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: @Mokhmad-SalekhKhekhaev  I did not put labels on the plots to indicate "j","n" values. I assumed you know how to do and add this. This will help know for which value of "j,n" each plot is  associated with.