# Assigning colors of a table of functions

Tags: plotting, color

I have a little problem.

I define:

```
f[x_,y_]=x^2_y^2
```

and

```
g[x_,y_]=x^4+y^4
```

Then I had create a sequence

```
seq[1]={f[x,y],g[x,y]}
```

Then I plotted 3-dimensionally the sequence of two functions:

```
Plot3D[seq[1],{x,-1,1},{y,-1,1}]
```

and I obtained

[image]

but the functions had the same color.
How can I plot the functions with two different colors (default colors are ok) ?

Thanks for any tips and helps!

Comment: Have you tried `Plot3D[seq[1] // Evaluate, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}]`?

Comment: Yes, it works perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: Lorenzo, to JM's comment, which really is the answer to your question, I would also like to add that, in general, you will want to define your functions using `SetDelayed` (`:=`) rather than just plain`Set` (`=`) (see [What is the difference between Set and SetDelayed?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/8829/27951)). Finally, objects like `{a, b}` are referred to as *lists* in Mathematica, rather than sequences. This matters because [`Sequence`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Sequence.html) objects do exist as well, but they are a different thing.