# Table generation with random variates inside. Mathematica

Tags: random, simulation, mathematica-online, table

I'm new on this forum, and I'm also a new user of the software Mathematica. For this reason, I'm sorry if my question will be unclear and / or dumb.
I have to make a numerical simulation with random generation of normally distributed error terms (10000 or 100000 times, which means 10000/100000 agents). I'm supposed to create a table with the payoff of all the agents reported. Each row should thus contain the payoff of one agent, whose individual error term is different from the others. For now, used the following code:

```
T1=RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0,1]];
T2=RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0,1]];
vi[azer_,vzer_,di_,pr_,T1_,T2_]:=If[azer*(vzer+di)+(1-azer)*(vzer+T1+T2)-pr>0,vzer+T1-pr,0];
Table[vi[azer,vzer,di,pr,T1[k],T2[k]],{k,1,10000}]
```

when I generate the table, T1 and T2 are not taken as random, but they are always the same. What am I doing wrong?
Thanks a lot for your time

Comment: Define `T1` and `T2` using `SetDelayed` rather than `Set`

Comment: Related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/8829/what-is-the-difference-between-set-and-setdelayed

Comment: thank you both !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what kind of output your a looking for, but the Wolfram Function Repository (WFR) function
[`RandomTabularDataset`](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/RandomTabularDataset)
for kind of tasks you outlined.

```mathematica
dsRand = ResourceFunction["RandomTabularDataset"][{12, {"T1", "T2"}}, "Generators" -> NormalDistribution[0, 1]];
dsRand[All, Append[#, "Value" -> vi[#T1, #T2]] &]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I think I found a solution

Answer (score 1):

I would simply make your table explicit, like this:

```
Table[
  vi[azer, vzer, di, pr, RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 1]], RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 1]]], 
  10]
```

You can reduce the verbosity from there if it bothers you by introducing "local" variables.

I have no idea what the semantics of your `vi` function is, but it looks like you were trying to "invoke" the variate generators inside of the table. So maybe you're wanting to parameterize `vi` with distributions? If so, then it would be clearer if the distributions were the arguments/parameters to vi. Maybe something like this:

```
vi2[azer_, vzer_, di_, pr_, dist1_, dist2_] :=
  With[
    {T1 = RandomVariate[dist1], T2 = RandomVariate[dist2]},
    If[
      azer*(vzer + di) + (1 - azer)*(vzer + T1 + T2) - pr > 0,
      vzer + T1 - pr,
      0]]
```

And then, of course, your table would look like this:

```
Table[vi2[azer, vzer, di, pr, NormalDistribution[0, 1], NormalDistribution[0, 1]], 10]
```

If you follow @BobHanlon's suggestion and use SetDelayed on your global T1 and T2, I would rename them (and you only need 1 for this example):

```
NormalVariate := RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 1]];
Table[vi[azer, vzer, di, pr, NormalVariate, NormalVariate], 10]
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!