# Application for StringDelete

Tags: string-manipulation

I have a list of strings:

```
lis:= {{"123 abc def 456"}, {"ghi jkl 789"}, {"012 mno pqr"}}
```

and I would like to remove digit characters from the beginning of each string (that has them) to give:

```
res:={{abc def 456"}, {"ghi jkl 789"}, {"mno pqr"}}
```

Thanks for suggestions!

Comment: Thanks Nasser and lericr!

Comment: Do you require as output `{{"abc def 456"}, {"ghi jkl 789"}, {"mno pqr"}}`  _or_  (as interpreted by @Nasser, and your accepted answer)  `{{"abc", "def", "456"}, {"ghi jkl 789"}, {"mno", "pqr"}}`?

Comment: Yeah, @user1066, now I'm confused.

Comment: @user1066 added second version if string should not have comments in it. Now it matches the output.

Comment: Possible not useful information @Suite401 as you have a high reputation... but SetDelayed (:=) is usually not the right option for assigning objects like this https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/8829/what-is-the-difference-between-set-and-setdelayed

Comment: You should probably unaccept my answer and select one of the others which uses more functional approach to solving this problem which is a better approach.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
StringDelete[#, RegularExpression["^[\\d\\s]+"]]&/@lis

(* {{"abc def 456"}, {"ghi jkl 789"}, {"mno pqr"}} *)
```

(Delete from the beginning of each string one or more digit characters (`\\d`) *or* whitespace characters (`\\s`), in any order)

Comment: Nice refinement. The OP was silent about whitespace, so I made a guess, but I like your guess better.

Answer (score 8):

```
StringTrim[#, StartOfString ~~ DigitCharacter ... ~~ WhitespaceCharacter ...] & /@ lis
```

or

```
StringTrim[#, RegularExpression["^\\d*\\s*"]] & /@ lis
```

Answer (score 5):

**Using `StringReplace`:**

```
lis = {{"123 abc def 456"}, {"ghi jkl 789"}, {"012 mno pqr"}, {"a 232"}, {"123abc"}, {"567    abc 12"}}

StringReplace[
    StartOfString ~~ DigitCharacter .. ~~ 
      Repeated[WhitespaceCharacter, {0, ∞}] ~~ x__ ~~ 
      EndOfString :> x][#] & /@ lis
```

You can choose to keep or replace leading/trailing spaces using the `Repeated`command as desired.

---

**Using `StringDelete`:** (as requested in the title)

```
StringDelete[
    StartOfString ~~ DigitCharacter .. ~~ 
     Repeated[WhitespaceCharacter, {0, ∞}]][#] & /@ lis
```

---

> {{"abc def 456"}, {"ghi jkl 789"}, {"mno pqr"}, {"a 232"}, {"abc"}, 
> {"abc 12"}}

Comment: (+1) Nice, @Syed! :-)

Answer (score 4):

Another method to do this is as follows:

```
 lis = {{"123 abc def 456"}, {"ghi jkl 789"}, {"012 mno pqr"}, {"a 232"}};

 SetAttributes[f, Listable];
 f[str_] := StringJoin[
    Apply[
            Function[
                Take[Characters @ #,
                    Span[
                        
       Function[Det[Position[#, FirstCase[#, _ ? LetterQ]]]][
        Characters @ #],
                        All
                    ]
                ]
            ],
            {str}
        ]
   ];
```

[image]

@Syed suggests an interesting approach to achieve the same thing, which is as follows:

```
chars = (StringPosition[_?LetterQ][#] & /@ lis // #[[All, -1, 1]] &) /. {a_, a_} :> {a, -1};
MapThread[StringTake[#1, #2] &, {lis, chars}] (*Thanks, Syed!*)
```

Comment: Try: `chars = (StringPosition[_?LetterQ][#] & /@ 
     lis  // #[[All, -1, 1]] &) /. {a_, a_} :> {a, -1}` and `MapThread[StringTake[#1, #2] &, {lis, chars}]`

Answer (score 3):

One possible way out of many

I saw the comments above. Here is a version to get the output as string and not list of strings if needed, change it to

```
lis={{"123 abc def 456"},{"ghi jkl 789"},{"012 mno pqr"},{"232 test"},{"1 a"}};
f[s_List]:=Module[{m,s0=First@s},
    m=StringSplit[s0];
    If[Head[ToExpression[First@m]]===Integer,{StringDrop[s0,StringLength[First@m]+1]},s]
];

Map[f, lis]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**Old answer**

```
lis={{"123 abc def 456"},{"ghi jkl 789"},{"012 mno pqr"},{"a 232"}}
f[s_List]:=Module[{m},
   m=StringSplit[s[[1]]];
   If[Head[ToExpression[First@m]]===Integer,Join[Rest[m]],s]
]
Map[f,lis]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: This doesn't match the expected output. Although, the expected output provided by the OP has a syntax error, so maybe I misinterpreted.

Answer (score 3):

Using `NumberString`:

```
NumberStringQ[x_String] := StringMatchQ[x, NumberString]

join[x_] := {StringJoin @ StringRiffle[{x}]}

skip[{_?NumberStringQ, x__}] := join[{x}]
skip[x_] := join[x]

skip @* First @* StringSplit /@ lis
```

{{"abc def 456"}, {"ghi jkl 789"}, {"mno pqr"}}

Comment: Is `NumberStringQ` a newly introduced function. I don't have it in v12.2. Or can include the required code for it?

Comment: Sorry - I added it

Comment: Please add a brace at the end of `join[x_]` or remove the one at the front?