# Exporting lists with two extensions to files

Tags: export, import

Continuation of [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/8822/4650): How to export if I need to have two extensions instead of one. E.g., in the previous case one can generate lists labeled L[1], L[2],.....and so on using a loop. But if I have 2 loops and hence two variables and the lists are labeled L[1,1], L[1,2],… then L[2,1], L[2,2],… How do I export them in wdx format?

Answer (score 2):

Make some 2D data:

```
data = RandomInteger[Range@2, {5, 3}];
```

Create a series of strings to represent the indices of the elements of data:

```
Array[ToString[#1] <> "_" <> ToString[#2] &, Dimensions@data]
```

> {{"1_1", "1_2", "1_3"}, {"2_1", "2_2", "2_3"}, {"3_1", "3_2", 
>     "3_3"}, {"4_1", "4_2", "4_3"}, {"5_1", "5_2", "5_3"}}

Then just add those strings into whatever basename and extension you are using for your files and use that with `Save`, `DumpSave` or `Export`.

Comment: Since you used `Dimensions`, perhaps `StringJoin[Riffle[ToString/@{##}, "_"]]&` would be more universal.

Comment: @VF1 That looks significantly different enough to be an answer :)

Answer (score 2):

If you have n-dimensional `data`, then create the names:

```
names = Array[StringJoin[Riffle[ToString/@{##}, "_"]]&, Dimensions[data]]
```

Then export each one:

```
MapThread[Export[#1 <> ".wdx", #2] &, {names, data}, Depth@data - 1]
```